# Wildcard with variable in Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell

Im sure this is just a syntax error, but im trying to search AD users, and I cannot figure out why this does not work:

```
Write-Host "Enter LastName or UserName:"
$x = Read-Host
Get-ADUser -Filter { SAMAccountName -like '*$x*' } -Properties DispalyName | FT -Properties DisplayName
```

Just doesnt return anything.  And im sure it is syntax with the "*". but not sure why.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$x is not expanded inside the Filter scriptblock, this should do the job:

```
$x = 'mini'
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '*$x*'" -Properties DisplayName | ft DisplayName 

DisplayName
-----------
Administrator
```

Alternatively, you could use ldap filter:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(samaccountname=*$x*)"
```

Comment: This works as well.  makes the "Read-Host" code a little cleaner.

Comment: I've some doubt that the `-Filter {}` is evaluated as a scriptblock.. because in my answer the variable is correctly evaluated.

Comment: It isn't evaluated on my system. i remember filing a bug on this, or maybe just reported this internally to MSFT, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: For anyone else who was in my situation, this doesn't work with curly braces (`-Filter { <value> }`). Attempting to do so fails with error `Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter": "Invalid filter syntax. For a description of the filter parameter syntax see the command help.`.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the above poster. Single quotes prevent variable expansion.
Double quotes will work.

```
PS H:\> $s = "smith"
PS H:\> Write-Host '*$s*' 
*$s*
PS H:\> Write-Host "*$s*" 
*smith*
```

There are still some cases where double quotes won't save you, e.g. with an object.

```
PS H:\> $psObj = New-Object PsCustomObject
PS H:\> $psobj | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -name s -value "smith"
PS H:\> Write-Host $psobj.s
smith
PS H:\> Write-Host "*$psobj.s*"
*@{s=smith}.s*
```

In that case, use string formatting:

```
PS H:\> Write-Host ("*{0}*" -f $psobj.s)
*smith*
```

Comment: Your last example can be solved with : `write-host "*$($psobj.s)*"`

Comment: I under stand what your saying, but it doesnt seem to answer my question.  because if i do this `PS C:\Windows\system32> $x = Read-Host "Enter Name"
Enter Name: smith

PS C:\Windows\system32> Write-Host "*$x*"
*smith*` it should work passing it into the Get-ADUser `Get-ADUser -Filter { (SAMAccountName -like "*$x*") }`  when just writing to the host, it comes out *smith* so i don't understand why it doesnt work in the filter.  Thanks for the object and variable expansion clarification, it was very helpful.

Comment: sorry for the formating, not sure how to do linebreaks in the comment section.  and there should be "*" around the smith, not italicized.

Answer (score 2):

try just changing this:

```
{ SAMAccountName -like "*$x*" }
```

Edit:

this should works:

```
$x = '*' + $(Read-Host 'Enter name') + '*'
get-aduser -Filter {name -like $x} -Properties DispalyName | FT -Properties DisplayName
```

Comment: i need to be a wild card, so if the person types smit i want it it return all smiths IE: ssmith, rsmith, smithie, etc etc.

Comment: does not work either.  I started there.  this does not work either "*" + $x + "*".  i also tried appending the $variable before passing into the cmdlet.  not sure what the deal is.

Comment: ummm.. I can test it now but try to declare `$x` like this `$global:x = Read-Host`

Comment: This works the best, and is 2x or 3x faster then the solution i posted.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works, just a little slow:

```
$x = Read-Host "Enter Name"

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties SAMAccountName | ? { $_.SAMAccountName -like "*$x*" } | Format-Table -Property SAMAccountName
```

Little differnt approach, but works non the less!  thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this in my powershell learning curve when using an object.

I read in a csv file of user id's and needed to search/match/filter on them, and as put before double quotes did not work there.

My solution was to use ToString() method on my object and set it to a scalar variable then use that variable in the filter. Worked great.

```
$user_records=Import-CSV .\20140430.userids.csv
```

The table had three columns "Name, ID, Department".
To get them in a search filter on their user id I used:

```
foreach ( $thisrow in $user_records ) {
$thisuser=$thisrow.Username.ToString()
Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $thisuser} -SearchBase "OU=Domain Users,DC=topofthecharts,DC=com" -Properties Department
```

}

This avoided my expansion and quotes troubles completely.