# Powershell pipeline objects from import-csv headaches

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, active-directory, import-csv

We have a big audit coming up, and we want to be sure that all termed employees' AD computer accounts have been deactivated. I have a .csv that has a unique identifier that we use - our schema includes that ID in the middle of the ADcomputer Name property. I am having enormous trouble correctly piping the imported csv objects *and their property* to the filter. I think. I'm not entirely sure. This is something like what I've been trying.

```
Import-Csv termname.csv | ForEach-Object
{ Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -Contains "$($_.id)" } } |
Export-Csv termcomp.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This "script" pulled a total of no content, while I KNOW that when I test

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -Contains $id }
```

where `$id` is that unique ID, I get hits on AD Computer objects. Likewise, testing this block

```
Import-Csv termname.csv | ForEach-Object { Get-ADComputer { Name -Contains $_.id }
```

PowerShell's error is:

```
..."Property 'id' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.
```

I think that I am misapprehending what precisely is an "object" in this case. Is the whole imported array an object, with a property of .id? Or is each row its own object, with a .id property? And, either way, why has PowerShell such strong objections to a pipeline object, which is, after all, its primary job?

Is there an entirely better way to go about this whole process? Am I somehow overthinking the whole mess?

**UPDATE**

As requested, sample contents of the csv file. Taking the suggestion to use wildcards instead, I've put the wildcards into the .csv itself, which, again, may not be the most elegant solution. But as long as it works! Here's the sample, copied from Notepad++

```
id
*rstarr56*
*jlennon58*
*pmcartney74*
*gharrison68*
```

Comment: Could you please share the CSV file content also. Atleast some of tha values so that we can see how exactly the content is coming in powershell. ?

Comment: The big issue I see is the use of contains, which is for testing is an item is in a collection. The simple answer would be to use like and * wildcards instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of digging, I found an answer here:

[Import-CSV and Foreach to use Get-ADUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112490/import-csv-and-foreach-to-use-get-aduser)

Thanks especially to [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6421240/mike-garuccio) for some great thinking about `-Like` and how to test the success of the code.

The line that ended up working was:

```
Import-Csv termname.csv | ForEach-Object {
   Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -Like '*$($_.id)*'"
} | Export-Csv termout.csv
```

Apparently, Powershell hates `{{}}`.

Thanks again, all!

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like your CSV file does not have an "ID" heading in it, causing that not to be an available property, easy fix there is to confirm the contents of the CSV file, if everything looks correct try running `Import-Csv termname.csv | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.id }` to confirm that the property is coming across correctly.  However you will also have trouble using `-Contains` here as that operator is meant to check if an array contains a particular value, you'll need to use `Name -Like "*$($_.id)*"`