# Getting the get-aduser Whenchanged property in to variable for log in script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following bit of code

```
$date = ((get-date).addmonths(-3))
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties whenChanged| Where-Object {$_.whenChanged -ge $date} | select name
```

This works fine and gives me a nice list of users that have not had there account updated in 3 months. But I need this as a log in script so I want it to say logicaly

```
if ((get-aduser <name> -Properties whenChanged) -ge $date) {do something} else {do nothing}
```

When ever I try this i get..

```
 $c = Get-ADUser street | Where-Object {$_.whenChanged -ge $date} | select whenchanged
write-host $c
@{whenchanged=07/09/2015 17:00:30}
```

I know there is a magic bit of syntax to make it work and I would be great ful for any pointers.

Comment: As an aside: It's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Result is an [Hashtable] Type you need to add the `-ExpandProperty` to the Select-Object Cmdlet to expand it, like this:

```
$c = Get-ADUser street -Properties whenChanged | Where-Object {$_.whenChanged -ge $date} | 
Select -ExpandProperty whenchanged
write-host $c
```

**-ExpandProperty**

Specifies a property to select, and indicates that an attempt should be made to expand that property. Wildcards are permitted in the property name.

For example, **if the specified property is an array, each value of the array is included in the output**. If the property contains an object, the properties of that object are displayed in the output.

Comment: `-ExpandProperty` is indeed the right answer, but it's not about _arrays_ per se (and in the OP's example a _single_ object is returned); it's about `Select-Object` returning a _custom object_ even if you specify only a single property to extract; `-ExpandProperty` bypasses creation of  the custom object and directly returns the requested property value.