# Identify home folders for user accounts that have been deleted

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

I have a large folder `E:\Users` that has a folder for each user by their logon name for example `E:\Users\jt10192`.

I want to loop through every folder in `E:\Users` and get a list of home folders that belonged to users that have since been deleted.

This is how far I've got, but I'm not sure what to run to lookup if `$folder` is a user and output something if not.

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object Name

foreach ($folder in $folders) {

       // lookup if $folder is a user and output something if not...

}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about your environment - for instance, is this an ActiveDirectory domain? What is your level of privilege? What research have you done toward solving this problem on your own, and what problems have you encountered in trying to use what you've found?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Apologies. I have updated the tags. Yes it's Active Directory and I am a Domain Admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using AD to lookup your users accounts:

```
$path = "E:\Users"
$folders = Get-ChildItem $path -Directory

ForEach ($folder in $folders) {
    If(Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $($folder.name)}){
        Write-Host "Found matching User for: $($folder.FullName)" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "No account found for folder: $($folder.FullName)" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Comment: `Get-ADUser` will throw an error if user does not exist and the `else` block will not be executed. Because of this I often use `Get-ADUser -Filter { SamAccountName -eq "JohnDoe" }` (or a `try/catch` construct.

Comment: @sodawillow So change `Get-ADUser $($folder.name)` to `Get-ADUser -Filter { SamAccountName -eq "$($folder.name)" }`?

Comment: Checked my script and I had actually used dsquery, but sticking with Get-ADUser and using the Filter is nicer. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: [Some tips about this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075502/get-aduser-filter-will-not-accept-a-variable)

Comment: This results in `Get-ADUser : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is
not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.`.

Comment: I changed it to `If(Get-ADUser -Filter "sAMAccountName -eq ""$($folder.name)"""){` and it works now. Accepting. Thanks.