# PowerShell - using an objects variable for -Filter

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working, and what to even search for.

I have a simple function Get-FileInput. It simply calls Import-CSV and checks for a specific column before passing on the data.

I have $filterType = "Name"

My test TSV is in the format

`db stuff   Name
1   2   spare40`

Then I have this

```
$data = Get-FileInput
foreach ($computer in $data)
{
    Get-ADComputer -Filter {$filterType -eq "comp1"} | Format-Table
    Write-Host "$($computer.$filterType)"
    Get-ADComputer -Filter {$filterType -eq "$($computer.$filterType)"} | Format-Table
}
```

The first Get-ADComputer works fine and outputs a table.

The Write-Host produces the output comp1 in the terminal.

The second Get-ADComputer runs, but does not output anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not use a *script block* (`{...}`) as the `-Filter` argument** - it works in simple cases (e.g., `{$filterType -eq "comp1"}`) but falls apart in more complex ones (`{$filterType -eq "$($computer.$filterType)"}`).

**The `-Filter` argument is of type `[string]`, and you should construct it as such**:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "$filterType -eq '$($computer.$filterType)'" | Format-Table
```

For background information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375) of mine.

Comment: @Spencel: Glad to hear it; my pleasure.