# How to output foreach into CSV using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, foreach, export-to-csv

I am displaying all users in a group with this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "UC_*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name   # UC_* is my group

foreach ($Group in $Groups){
Write-Output "Group" 
Write-Output "-----"
$Group
Write-Output ""
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | select -Property Name, samaccountname 
Write-Output ""
}
```

I want to output this to a CSV but when I do, it looks like each line is getting overwritten by the next line in the loop so there is no data in the CSV.  This is not working properly:

```
# Get users in a group or groups

Import-Module ActiveDirectory


Function Get-Users {
    $Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "UC_*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name   # UC_* is my group

    foreach ($Group in $Groups){
    Write-Output "Group" 
    Write-Output "-----"
    $Group
    Write-Output ""
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | select -Property Name, samaccountname 
    Write-Output ""
    }
}

Get-Users | export-csv "c:\temp\myfile.csv"
```

How can I output all content to a CSV properly?

Comment: As an aside: using a script block (`{...}`) as the `-Filter` argument - even though it works in this _particular_ case - is a bad idea; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375) (of mine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of your function is `Write-output`'s, `$Group`, and the objects returned from `Get-ADGroupMember`. This collection of different objects makes it not able to be exported by the `Export-CSV`, but would be something for a text document via `Out-File`.

If you want to export to a csv, you need to create a collection of consistent objects with the properties you want to export:

So we'll loop over each group with `ForEach-Object`, and store the group membership in `$members`. Then can loop over that with `foreach`, this means that we can still use the information from the `ForEach-Object` loop in the `$_` to get the name of the group, and the user information in `$member` and create an object for every user with just the information that's needed by making a `[pscustomobject]`

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like 'UC_*'" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember $_
        foreach ($member in $members) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                "Group Name"     = $_.Name
                "SamAccountName" = $member.SamAccountName
                "User Name"      = $member.name
            }
        }
    } |
    Export-Csv "c:\temp\myfile.csv"
```

Also as @mklement0 mentioned, it's best practice to not use scriptblock's with the filters on the AD cmdlets. [His excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075502/get-aduser-filter-will-not-accept-a-variable/44184818#44184818) here gives details why.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "UC_*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name   # UC_* is my group

$Groups | Export-Csv  "c:\temp\myfile.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for outputting to a CSV. Using `Export-CSV` will overwrite a file that is already there. So you can put everything into a variable and output that to a CSV or you can add `-Append` to the `Export-CSV` cmdlet call. This will append data rather than overwrite it.

Comment: I do want to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data you're parsing in your function in an object.

For example, change this...

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "UC_*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name   # UC_* is my group

foreach ($Group in $Groups){
Write-Output "Group" 
Write-Output "-----"
$Group
Write-Output ""
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | select -Property Name, samaccountname 
Write-Output ""
```

... to something like this ...

```
$users = @()

$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "UC_*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name

$groups | % {

    $group | New-Object System.Object
    $group | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name GroupName -Value $_

        Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ | Select -Property Name, samaccountname | % {

$group | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MemberName -Value $_.Name
$group | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name samaccountname -Value $_.samaccountname


}


    $users += $group

}
```

I haven't tested the code above, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: I think you'll run into an issue here that `$group.members` will be an object rather than strings. The solution could be to use `Out-String` or to make an object per user. Only can you output with `Export-CSV`

Comment: Good point. I made a further edit to try to take care of that, though it's screwed up the formatting and I'm not sure how to fix it. Is there a way of seeing the underlying code block markup?