# Passing a variable from Powershell to DISM

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to run DISM via Powershell but I seem to have a problem passing a variable from Powershell to DISM. I am open to suggestions if there is a better way to pass my drive letter $dl to DISM.

```
$dl=(Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "\\domain\shares$\IT\ISO\Desktops\Microsoft\SW_DVD5_WIN_EDU_10_1703_64BIT_English_MLF_X21-36554.ISO" -PassThru | Get-Volume).DriveLetter

RunAs /user:domain\svcaccount (Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:{$dl}:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess)
```

Comment: `{$dl}` -> `${dl}`

Comment: thanks, but I did try that and it still failed.  I will try again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075502/get-aduser-filter-will-not-accept-a-variable has a great section on script blocks that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Covert the whole argument to a single string.

```
$dl = $dl + ':\sources\sxs'
RunAs /user:domain\svcaccount (Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:$dl /LimitAccess)
```