# Add a new column to data row

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I've queried certain information from an SQL database and put it into a variable named `$tablevalue`. Now I want add new column on the output and that requires querying active directory for the status of a computer object

`$tablevalue` has a typename `System.Data.DataRow`

Sample query:

```
$tablevalue | select netbios_name0, client0, @{n='ADComputer_Enabled';e={
    (Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like {$_.netbios_name0} | select Enabled)
}}
```

Desired output:

```
netbios_name0, client0, ADComputer_enabled
computer1      version1 True
computer1      version1 False
```

Comment: `select Enabled` -> `select -Expand Enabled`?

Comment: hello Ansgar thanks for the feedback but i think the issue is with this expression.
    (Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like {$_.netbios_name0}

Comment: the $_.netbios_name is not being recognized, i'm unable to input this to the get-adcomputer

Comment: $tablevalue | select netbios_name0, client0, @{n='ADComputer_Enabled';e={
    (Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like {$_.netbios_name0} | select Enabled)
}}

Comment: a simple piping of the same script will work fine                            

example:  $tablevalue | select netbios_name0, client0, @{n='ADComputer_Enabled';e={(write-host $_.netbios_name0)}}

the idea is that each netbios_name0 in the $tablevalue, i want to query computer object attribute value for "enabled" in active directory using get-adcomputer cmdlet and add a column in the final output to display netbiosname, client0 from $tablevalue plus a new column name ADComputer_Enabled that contains the status of each machine in terms ADcomputer attribute "Enabled" (True/False)

Comment: `Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like {$_.netbios_name0} | select Enabled` -> `Get-ADComputer -Filter "name -like '*$($_.netbios_name0)*'" | select -Expand Enabled`. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/1630171).

Comment: Thanks Ansgar! This works for me. the processing is a little slow though but this is exactly what I've been trying to make work. really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you don't need fuzzy matches change `-like '*$($_.netbios_name0)*'` to `-eq '$($_.netbios_name0)'`. That might speed up processing a little. Alternatively try reading all computer objects (or their `Enabled` property) into a hashtable using their NetBIOS name as the key, then do a hashtable lookup in the calculated property.

Comment: Thanks again Ansgar. your suggested alternative looks ok as well. I'll try to hack my way through it.