# PowerShell script: AD query based on computer-name pattern not returning results

Tags: powershell, active-directory, filtering

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that takes a list from an array of partial machine names and return them to me

So far, I've imported *ActiveDirectory* module and setup the array. I then run a *foreach* against the array but it doesn't return any results, instead going to a new line.

I have tried assigning the *Get-ADComputer* line to a variable and calling the variable. I have also tried to use the *Return* and not achieved my results.

The results can just print out in a list on the screen, that's OK. I just need it to return the results and then I can build up from that.

This is what I have done so far:

```
$getPC = @("7477", "7473", "7474")
foreach ($i in $getPC)
{
    Get-ADComputer -filter {name -like "*$i*"} | select name
}
```

When I run the *Get-ADComputer* line alone, and put in the positional parameter, I have no problems. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the practice is widespread, **do not use *script blocks* (`{ ... }`) as  the `-Filter` argument**.

**Construct your `-Filter` as a *string***, which is the `-Filter` parameter's actual type; you'll avoid many obscure problems if you construct it as such.

So, instead of:

```
-Filter { Name -like "*$i*" } # WRONG - do not use { ... }
```

use:

```
-Filter "Name -like '*$_*'" # OK - use of a string
```

For an explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375) of mine.

---

As an aside, you could simplify your command somewhat using a single pipeline with the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*, in whose script block the automatic `$_` variable (alias name: `$PSItem`) represents the input object at hand:

```
"7477", "7473", "7474" |
  ForEach-Object { Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '*$_*'"} |
    Select-Object Name
```

Regarding your original command: As [Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6590026/seth) recommends, it's better to use a more descriptive loop variable name than `$i`, such as `$computer`.

Comment: Oops! Thanks, @Seth, indeed my mistake. I've fixed the answer and also restructured it for clarity; I've also added your recommendation re naming the loop variable, so we can clean up the comments here.