# Adding groups to AD user with a ps1 script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

With following script I'd like to add a group to an AD user, but it doesn't do it, and I get no error.

```
param($Userid,$AdditionalGroup)

# Get user
$User = Get-ADUser `
    -Filter "SamAccountName -eq $Userid"

# Add comment
Add-ADGroupMember `
    -Identity $AdditionalGroup `
    -Members $User
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering like that didn't work for me (and generated an error), however adding `'` before and after $Userid did the trick.

```
param($Userid,$AdditionalGroup)

# Get user
$User = Get-ADUser `
    -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$Userid'"

# Add comment
Add-ADGroupMember `
    -Identity $AdditionalGroup `
    -Members $User
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're only doing a straight `-eq` match on sAMAccountName you don't need to use `-Filter`, the `Identity` param will accept this along with other inputs:

> - A distinguished name
> - A GUID (objectGUID)
> - A security identifier (objectSid)
> - A SAM account name (sAMAccountName)
>
> ([documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser#required-parameters))

Which makes your code very simple:

```
$User = Get-ADUser -Identity $Userid
```

---

To simplify it even further, you don't even need to use `Get-ADUser` at all!

`Add-ADGroupMember -Members` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember#required-parameters)) accepts the same parameters as I mentioned for `Identity` ...

So you can use `$UserID` directly:

```
param($Userid,$AdditionalGroup)

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $AdditionalGroup -Members $UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work (without the single quotes):

```
$User = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $Userid}
```

Comment: Yes, but it's [better to avoid the use of script blocks as the `-Filter` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375)

Comment: Funny, @mklement0 you beat me to it while I was looking for that particular post of yours. :)

Comment: $Mind = "BLOWN!"

Comment: you know.  this is probably why i so constantly get ticked off with the -Filter parameter and instead just end up using | ?{$_.whatever -eq "whatever"} instead.