# Disconnect RDS User Based On Username Input Variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to create a script that can force logoff of users in an RDS server farm environment. There are 1 of 4 RDS servers that users can be be logged into, and I am trying to make this so you run the script, enter a username and it will force logoff of the user. So far I have:

```
import-module remotedesktop
$user = read-host -prompt 'Enter Username you want to disconnect'
$sid = Get-RDUserSession | Where-Object -filter {$_.UserName -eq $user} | format-wide -Property UnifiedSessionID
$server = Get-RDUserSession | Where-Object -filter {$_.UserName -eq $user} | format-wide -Property HostServer
Invoke-RDUserLogoff -HostServer "$server" -UnifiedSessionID $sid
```

The only problem with this in the last line it doesn't like the `$sid` variable as the input for that item. If I do a `write-output $sid` it displays the correct `UnifiedSessionID` number.

I could be doing this the wrong way altogether, but I just need a way to disconnect user sessions based on a username input when prompted.

Comment: As an aside: [Using script blocks (`{...}`) as `-Filter` arguments is best avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `$sid` variable is being loaded with data whose datatype is the datatype of the last action in the pipeline, i.e., `format-wide`. So, the datatype of `$sid` may be something like `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData`.

You can verify by executing the command `$sid | get-member` right after `$sid` is loaded.

It may be that the `-UnifiedSessionID` argument of `Invoke-RDUserLogoff` has to be a string, and `$sid` is not a `string`

You'll have to cast `$sid` to `string` if that's the case

Comment: That's exactly what the datatype was. Sorry, how exactly would I convert that datatype to a string?

Comment: Nevermind I just added `| out-string`to the the end and it works fine now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good to hear - its easy to forget that `PowerShell` `cmdlets` typically accept and emit `object-based` entities. The `Get-Member` `cmdlet` is your friend because it can tell you what the `datatype` is of any object

Comment: While you _may_ situationally be able to retrieve the data underlying the objects produced by `Format-*` cmdlets, the far better approach is to not use those cmdlets in the first place when the intent is _programmatic_ processing of the output. You should make that clear  in your answer.

Comment: @mklement0: Agreed. Your answer addressed the root cause. However, I think we all have to consider that his requirements may also demand a formatted output. If I were to change my answer, I guess I would both address the issue/bug and his original (implied) requirements

Comment: Since command output is being captured in _variables_, there is no display output and therefore no need for formatting. The OP only used `Format-Wide` because it _appeared_ that it extracted the property values of interest, when it reality it created `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.*]` instances with _formatting instructions_.

Comment: Furthermore, casting to `[string]` doesn't actually work here; try `[string] (Get-Item / | Format-Wide -Property Name)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you never get the UnifiedSessionID store with format-wide

Use select -ExpandProperty

```
import-module remotedesktop

$user = read-host -prompt 'Enter Username you want to disconnect'

$sid = Get-RDUserSession | Where-Object -filter {$_.UserName -eq $user} | select -ExpandProperty UnifiedSessionID

$server = Get-RDUserSession | Where-Object -filter {$_.UserName -eq $user} | select -ExpandProperty HostServer

Invoke-RDUserLogoff -HostServer "$server" -UnifiedSessionID $sid
```

Answer (score 1):

> I could be doing this the wrong way altogether

Indeed:

- `Format-*` cmdlets are only meant to produce output *for display*.

  - *Never* use them for *programmatic processing*.
- For *programmatic processing*, use `Select-Object`:

  - Use `Select-Object <prop1>, ...` to extract *multiple* properties as a *custom object*.
  - Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty <prop>` to extract a *single* property's *value*.

[Frédéric Bonneau's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50534361/45375) shows you how to do that in your case.

Comment: I see, this is good information. I starting throwing together stuff in powershell literally 2 days ago