# Powershell get-adcomputer - filter options object values

Tags: powershell, object, casting

```
$server = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "a OU in a domain*" -Filter {Name -like "*79234*"} | Select -Property *
```

This work it pulls the computer object like I want. A computer object with those numbers in the name.

In previous code I define a

```
$array[$where] = 79234 
$server = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "a OU in a domain*" -Filter {Name -like "*$($array[$where])*"} | Select -Property *
```

Fails and does not give me my match. Why?

"*$($array[$where])*" = 79234 in the commandline..

I did use work around it by create the object name I'd searching for before I search

```
$FilterName = "*$($Array[$Where])*"

$server = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "a OU in a domain*" -Filter {Name -like $filterObjectname} | Select -Property *
```

Gives me the correct object, I think the root issue is they way the values are past between the objects (casting?) but I'm missing it.

Comment: This question already has an answer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075502/get-aduser-filter-will-not-accept-a-variable It has a better explanation of anything I could come up with - but I think it has to do with the concept of expanding the value of the variable in the string.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [this tutorial with arrays](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-variables,2-797.html). you can not define an array element in powershell like you did.

you can create a hashtable like so:

```
$array = @{}
```

and then add elements like:

```
$array.asdf = 'qwert'
```

or

```
$array.$where = 'value'
```

so for your sample code I would suggest

```
$array = @{}
$array.$where = 79234
$FilterName = $array.$where
```

Comment: sorry, I should of been more clear "$($array[$where])" = 79234 in the command line.. is not a declaration its a expanded value or what the command line returns.

Comment: and what type of object is `$array`?

Comment: $array = @{} was a array