# Powershell script to add users to A/D group from .csv using email address only?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server-2010

```
Import-CSV "C:\users\Balbahagw\desktop\test1.csv" | 
  Foreach-Object {
    $aduser = Get-ADUser -Filter { EmailAddress -eq $_.'EmailAddress' }
    if( $aduser ) {
      Write-Output "Adding user $($aduser.SamAccountName) to groupname"
      Add-ADGroupMember -Identity tech-103 -Members $aduser
    } else {
      Write-Warning "Could not find user in AD with email address $($_.EmailAddress)"
    }
  }
```

Script is working now, however it can't find the user in AD with the email address.

Comment: The error message tells you precisely what went wrong.

Comment: You want -Members not -User. At a powershell prompt type: `Get-Help Add-ADGroupMember -Detailed`

Comment: Dude, don't invent parameters that don't exist. PowerShell tends to take issue with that. Read up on the cmdlet here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps>

Comment: The object that I'm trying to import can't be found under the domain

Comment: Instead of lambasting a user for misunderstanding an API, maybe try answering the question with how they can do it correctly and explain where they were wrong.

Comment: @BelairAlbahagwi I updated your question to use the correct column name in your original command.

Comment: @BelairAlbahagwi at this point I think we will need to see a sample of your CSV file. This code works for me.

Comment: nevermind, found some strangeness with the brackets. I'm updating my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You need to first resolve the `ADUser` object matching that email address, the `-Identity` parameter won't auto-resolve based on the `EmailAddress` field of an `ADUser`. Assuming the `EmailAddress` property is set appropriately on the user object in AD, and assuming the column name for the email address in your CSV is `ExternalEmailAddress`, this should work:

```
Import-CSV "C:\users\user\desktop\test1.csv" | Foreach-Object {
  $aduser = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_.EmailAddress)'"
  if( $aduser ) {
    Write-Output "Adding user $($aduser.SamAccountName) to groupname"
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity groupname -Members $aduser
  } else {
    Write-Warning "Could not find user in AD with email address $($_.EmailAddress)"
  }
}
```

Note that if the ADUser does not have the email address set, you will not be able to match that AD user to an email.

Here are the docs for `Add-ADGroupMember`, you may want to read up on them for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adgroupmember?view=winserver2012-ps&viewFallbackFrom=winserver2012r2-ps

**EDIT**: Found some strangeness with using brackets and the $PSitem, so I changed it to use a string-based filter.

**EDIT 2**: Found the cause for why using a variable in a bracket-based `-Filter` doesn't work (which is how I had originally written this), and in fact is not recommended when scripting: [Get-Aduser -Filter will not accept a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075502/get-aduser-filter-will-not-accept-a-variable/44184818#44184818)

Comment: I'm receiving a new error that the email address is not found in object of type

Comment: Not sure which version of the AD cmdlets or Powershell you are running, you might try adding `-Properties EmailAddress` parameter to the `Get-ADuser` cmdlet. But the code as I wrote it above is working for me without having to specify the additional EmailAddress parameter.

Comment: Nvm... Command worked! but the script can't find the email address. However, when I open the exchange console and when I run get-aduser the email address is there...

Comment: What do you mean the script can't find the email address? Is it outputting "WARNING: Could not find user in AD with email address...."?

Comment: Yes. The script worked but the output is saying WARNING: Could not find user in AD with email address. I used the get-aduser -identity user -properties emailaddress command and the email is there

Comment: In your CSV, what is the name of the column with the email address in it? If there are spaces in the column name make sure to include those.

Comment: The name of the column is emailaddress. No spaces.

Comment: The command in your question suggests it's **externalemailaddress**. I'll update my answer quick.

Comment: Thank you so much Bender! I have a new distribution list that needs 3200 users and I need an efficient way to add them.

Comment: What did you update? I took out external in the script

Comment: Same thing, changed `$_.ExternalEmailAddress` to `$_.EmailAddress`

Comment: Still unable to find user in AD with the email address. That's really weird

Comment: I found some strangeness when using the brackets and trying to use the $PSItem object. I changed it to use a double-quotation based Filter, and the ADUser resolution is working from my local test case.

Comment: Better. New error states that I have insufficient access rights to perform the operation. I'm going to work with Identity Management and go from there. Thanks Bender!

Comment: Sounds good. If you're getting far enough to see that you don't have permission to perform the operation then the script is working. Just gotta get your access fixed.