# Contradictory values from Active Directory regarding password expiry date

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windowsdomainaccount

I am using Powershell to determine the password expiry date for domain accounts. I have used the following command to get this information:

`Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq "<username>"} -Properties "DisplayName" , "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"`

I then covert this value to a meaningful date by using:

`[datetime]::FromFileTime(<computed filetime from above command>)`

This works fine for all the domains I use, except one. In that domain I get a value of `9223372036854775807` as the `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed`. I am not able to use the `FromFileTime` function to convert this number into a date. It throws as error. Upon researching I have found that this number means that the password is set not to expire. However, I know that passwords do expire in this domain. Further, the `PasswordNeverExpires` property from the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet shows as `False`.

How can I get `9223372036854775807` from `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` attribute and get a `False` from the `PasswordNeverExpires` property? This seems like a contradiction. What am I missing? Are there other situations when `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` could be `9223372036854775807` too? Thanks.

Comment: As an aside: Using a script block (`{ ... }`) as a `-Filter` argument is [best avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223410.aspx) lists *several* conditions in which `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` returns `9223372036854775807` aka `0x7fffffffffffffff` aka `[int64]::MaxValue` (`TO` refers to a given *t*arget *o*bject):

> If any of the `ADS_UF_SMARTCARD_REQUIRED`, `ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD`, `ADS_UF_WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT`, `ADS_UF_SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT`, `ADS_UF_INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT` bits is set in `TO!userAccountControl`, then `TO!msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` = `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.
>   [...]
>   Else, if `Effective-MaximumPasswordAge = 0x8000000000000000`, then `TO!msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` = `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` (where `Effective-MaximumPasswordAge` is defined in [MS-SAMR] section 3.1.1.5).

---

Without knowing all the details, it seems that the `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` property returning `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` indicates that there is *effectively* no password expiration, for a variety of reasons, only *one* of which is `PasswordNeverExpires` being set to `$True`.

Therefore, you could filter out such values:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '<username>'" `
           -Properties DisplayName, msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed |                    #`
  Where { $_.msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed -ne 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF } | ForEach {
      # ...
      $dt = [datetime]::FromFileTime($_.msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed)
    }
```

It may even be possible to incorporate the test for `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` into the `-Filter` argument.

<sup>As an aside: Note that I've used a *string* rather than a script block (`{ ... }`) as the `-Filter` argument, because using script blocks is [best avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a DC at the moment to test but theoretically this can work.

1. Get the Password Policy of the domain with `Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -Identity Domain.com`
2. Get the `passwordLastSet` property of a user like this: `(Get-ADUser -Identity <UserName> -Properties *).PasswordlastSet` and convert to appropriate `[datetime]` object based on the domain's Culture: [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-culture?view=powershell-6) `Get-Culture`. `DateTime` format may change based on regional settings like US and UK.
3. Now that you have the `passwordpolicy` of say 60 days and the `passwordlastset` date, it is simple math to determine if the password is expiring or not.

Alternately, on 2016 servers, you can also use something like:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 10.00:00:00
```