# Using comparison operators on parameters of Powershell cmdlets

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm trying to use the [`Get-BrokerDesktop`](https://docs.citrix.com/de-de/xenapp-and-xendesktop/7-6/cds-sdk-wrapper-rho/xad-commands/citrix-broker-admin-v2-wrapper-xd76/get-brokerdesktop-xd76.html) cmdlet,

Like any other Powershell cmdlets I can pass it parameters to filter out the results to my needs. So, I could do something like,

```
Get-brokerdesktop  -RegistrationState Unregistered
```

Which would return an object that only has `Unregistered` as its `RegistrationState`.

How would I go about having the ones that are not `Unregistered`?

I tried,

```
Get-brokerdesktop  -RegistrationState -ne Unregistered
```

Which is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just noticed an example at the bottom of the linked documentation...

The trick here is to use `-Filter` like so,

```
Get-BrokerDesktop -Filter { RegistrationState -ne 'Unregistered' }
```

Or even better in this case, as proposed by @TheIncorrigible1,

```
-Filter 'RegistrationState -ne "Unregistered"'
```

Comment: Do not use scriptblocks for filters unless the type of the parameter is a scriptblock.. It just gets converted to a string and can cause annoying bugs.

Comment: How can I alternatively run it then ?

Comment: `-Filter 'RegistrationState -ne "Unregistered"'`

Comment: Also: `This cmdlet is now deprecated, please use Get-BrokerMachine.`

Comment: @scharette: To add a little backstory: The misguided use of script blocks as `-Filter` arguments is as unfortunate as it is misguided, and cmdlet publishers using it in their own doc examples is even more so. If you want the details on why script blocks should be avoided: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you for link really interesting,