# Filter by two properties with Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Purgatory,DC=domain,DC=com" -Filter {'enabled -eq $false' -and 'whenChanged -lt $ChangeDate'}
```

I cant figure out how to filter by two traits. I want to filter by disabled users that are older than the $ChangeDate variable. If I filter just by `'enabled -eq $false'`, it works, and if I filter just by `'whenChanged -lt $ChangeDate'` , it works. But if i use the -and to combine them, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should **[avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375)**.

Ultimately, **whatever is passed to the `-Filter` parameter is a *string***, and using `{ ... }` only obscures that fact, because it falsely suggests that the enclosed expression is a piece of *PowerShell* code - it is not; it is a severely constrained, PowerShell-*like* language described in [`Get-Help about_ActiveDirectory_Filter`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

**What muddies the waters is that the AD provider happens to recognize *simple variable references* (e.g., `$ChangeDate`)** in the strings it ultimately receives (and use of `{ ... }` effectively passes `...` as a *string literal*), whereas any *expression* (e.g., `$ChangeDate.Year`) is *not* recognized.

- Generally, the safest approach is to use *expandable* (interpolating) strings (double-quoted; `"..."`) as `-Filter` arguments and "bake in" variable values; that is, PowerShell replaces the variable references with their values *before* the AD provider sees the string.
- However, it's unclear how *date* values must be represented inside such a string in order to be recognized as such, so taking advantage of the 
  variable interpretation offered by the *AD* provider happens to be the safest choice in *this* case (note the use of *single* quotes (`'...'`), which means that the string is passed as-is - PowerShell performs no interpolation):

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Purgatory,DC=domain,DC=com" `
  -Filter 'enabled -eq $false -and whenChanged -lt $ChangeDate'
```

Again, be aware that you're passing a *string literal* to `-Filter`, and that it is the *AD provider* interpreting the embedded variable references, which only works with *simple variable references*, not *expressions*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

`{'enabled -eq $false' -and 'whenChanged -lt $ChangeDate'}` is effectively passed by calling the `.ToString()` method on it, which passes everything between the `{` and `}` *as-is*.

That is, the cmdlet / AD provider sees
`'enabled -eq $false' -and 'whenChanged -lt $ChangeDate'`
as the string value, *including the single quotes*, which is not what you intended.

Comment: I'm trying to do this (with Get-ADComputer) where one of the filters needs to be `'OperatingSystem -like "<os>"'`, where `<os>` is a variable that may contain spaces, e.g. `"*windows 7*"`. I can use `'OperatingSystem -like $os'` and it works, but that's kind of scary since you're not really quoting the value of `$os`. However `'OperatingSystem -like "$os"'` returns no results and `'OperatingSystem -like ``"$os``"'` (markdown won't let me use single backticks there) throws a parsing error. How can I ensure that spaces in `$os` are safely quoted, or do I not need to worry about it?

Comment: @mmseng: `'OperatingSystem -like $os'` works thanks to the AD provider's ability to recognize simple variable references. If you want to let PowerShell perform string interpolation up front, you must use `"..."`, not `'...'`: that is, use either `"OperatingSystem -like '$os'"` or `"OperatingSystem -like \`"$os\`""`.

Comment: That's fine for the single query of `$os`, but I can't see how you combine that with a date, which also needs to be quoted and safely interpreted by the AD provider, as you mentioned in your answer. That is, neither `"LastLogonTimeStamp -lt \`"$time\`" -and OperatingSystem -like \`"$os\`""`, nor `'LastLogonTimeStamp -lt "$time" -and OperatingSystem -like "$os"'` will work properly.

Comment: @mmseng: To use date-time variables, you _must_ rely on the AD provider's variable access; whenever you do: use outer single-quoting (`'...'`) and do _not_ use embedded quoting around the operands: `'LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time -and OperatingSystem -like $OSFilter'`, but remember that only simple variable references, not expressions with property access can be used. If you have follow-up questions, please create a new question post.