# Get SamAccountName from list of various names

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a list of names taken from Oracle that Im trying to find the SamAccountName for. The file is a CSV and some names are "last, first" or "last, first middle initial" and some have three or four names like "alpha bravo charlie delta". The names in the list are likely not the same as listed in AD. Trying to figure out how to sort through this to find AD accounts. The code I currently have is not producing any results.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Csv "\\server\users\folder\Oracle_HR.csv" 

ForEach-Object{    
  Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like "'$($_.name)'"} -Properties Name |
    Select-Object Name,SamAccountName |
      Export-CSV "\\server\users\folder\Oracle_ADs.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: As an aside: It's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers by [Gabriel Luci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53540731/45375) and [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53540734/45375) **give good advice on "fuzzy" filtering of AD users**.<sup>[1]</sup>

However, your primary problem is that **your `ForEach-Object` call is not receiving pipeline input**, because you haven't connected it to output from the `Import-Csv` call.

- Simply join the two commands with `|`:

  ```
   Import-Csv "\\server\users\folder\Oracle_HR.csv" | ForEach-Object { # ...
  ```

Secondarily, your **`-Filter` argument `{ Name -like "'$($_.name)'"}` mistakenly applies *two* layers of quoting** and is **missing wildcard characters**, given that `-like` compares against the *entire field*, yet you want *substring* matching.

- Since it's better to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375), use a *string*:

  ```
  "Name -like `"*$($_.name)*`"" # Note the enclosing '*' to match substrings
  ```
- Note that I've used embedded `"` quoting (escaped as `` `" ``) rather than `'` quoting, so as not to break the filter with names that contain `'`, such as `O'Malley`.
- That said, **if, as your question suggests, the names in your CSV data aren't direct substrings of the AD users' `.Name` property values, the above filter will *not* be enough, and even the ANR (Ambiguous Name Resolution) technique shown in the linked answers may not be enough.**

Thirdly, **your `Export-Csv` call is misplaced**: because it is inside the `ForEach-Object` script block, the same output file gets overwritten in every iteration.

- Restructure your command as follows:

  ```
   Import-Csv ... | ForEach-Object { ... } | Export-Csv ...
  ```

---

**Optional reading: `ForEach-Object` behavior when *not* providing pipeline input**:

- The associated script block is executed *once*.
- `$_`, the automatic variable that contains the current input object, is `$null`.

---

[1] Note that the **search term in the LDAP filter may need *escaping*** ; per [this article](https://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm), the characters `* ( ) \ NUL` require escaping and must be escaped as `\<hh>`, where `<hh>` is the two-digit hex representation of the char's ASCII code (e.g., `*` must be escaped as `\2A`):

```
$escapedName = -join $(foreach ($c in [char[]] $_.name) { if ('*', '\', '(', ')', "`0" -contains $c) { '\' + ([int] $c).ToString('X2') } else { $c } }) 

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$escapedName)"
```

With `$_.name` containing string `` "James* (Jimmy) Smith\Smyth`0" ``, `$escapedName` would evaluate to literal `James\2A \28Jimmy\29 Smith\5CSmyth\00`

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the property names in PowerShell are not named the same as the attributes in AD. The `Name` property corresponds to both the `name` and `cn` attributes in AD (both attributes are always the same).

There is also `DisplayName` (`displayName` in AD), `GivenName` (`givenName`), and `Surname` (`sn`). You could try matching against the `DisplayName`:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.name)'"
```

If none of those properties match your data exactly, you will have some trouble. No one thing you do will probably work for every account. Hopefully this is just a one-time job and you can work through them in pieces (try one thing, take out the ones that work, and try something different on the rest).

One thing you can try is using AD's [Ambiguous Name Resolution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx) (ANR), which will match a search string against several different attributes and even match a first and last name against `givenName` and `sn`. That might work with some in your list. You would use it like this:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$($_.name))"
```

If none of that works, you'll have to split the names (for example, by spaces: `$_.name.Split(" ")`) and try to match pieces of it to different attributes. You'll have to look at your data and see what works.

Comment: I get an error when using that as a filter. 
'Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized'

Comment: See the answer from @mklement0 for the reason why.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use the [Ambiguous Name Resolution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx) feature in Active Directory.

It'll do fuzzy matching against multiple attributes, like the `displayName`, `Name` and `mail` attributes (among others), so it's pretty good for this exact kind of scenario where you don't necessarily know the order or the names or the full name up front:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(anr=$($_.name)))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `LDAPFilter` and Ambiguous Name Resolution (`anr`) with `Get-ADUser`. The algorithm looks up several name fields in different orders to find matches:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=John Doe)"
```

Or modifying your code:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$($_.name))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$allUsers = Get-Content "\\server\users\folder\Oracle_HR.csv"
$users = @()
ForEach($obj in $allUsers){
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter { GivenName -like $obj} -Properties Name, samAccountName
    if(!$user){
        $user = Get-ADUser -Filter { SurName -like $obj} -Properties Name, samAccountName
    }
    if(!$user){
        $user = Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like $obj} -Properties Name, samAccountName
    }
    if(!$user){
        Write-Host "User $obj could not be found" -ForegroundColor Red
    }else{
        $users += $user
    }       
}

$users | Select-Object Name,SamAccountName | Export-CSV "\\server\users\folder\Oracle_ADs.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

You might need to split the values also like:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$allUsers = Get-Content "\\server\users\folder\Oracle_HR.csv"
$users = @()
ForEach($obj in $allUsers){
    $objSplit = $obj.Split(",")
    foreach($split in $objSplit){
        $user = Get-ADUser -Filter { GivenName -like $split} -Properties Name, samAccountName
        if(!$user){
            $user = Get-ADUser -Filter { SurName -like $split} -Properties Name, samAccountName
        }
        if(!$user){
            $user = Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like $split} -Properties Name, samAccountName
        }
        if(!$user){
            Write-Host "User $split could not be found" -ForegroundColor Red
        }else{
            if($users.samAccountName -notcontains $user.SamAccountName){
                $users += $user
            }
        }
    }      
}

$users | Select-Object Name,SamAccountName | Export-CSV "\\server\users\folder\Oracle_ADs.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those gave any results, but thanks.