# *$($name.text)* does not work can you explain?

Tags: powershell, filter, active-directory

I try to understand why this does not work

```
get-aduser -filter {Name -like "*$($Name.text)*"}
```

I understand that $($name.text) means can you take this this not a string value "" .

Thank you for your help .

Comment: You getting an error? What happens why you run that snippet on your system?

Comment: the reason it fails is because - despite LOTS of online samples of scriptblocks - the `-Filter` parameter is actually a **_string_** parameter. [*sigh ...*] the scriptblock will work for very simple things, but compound/complex $Vars will almost always fail. ///// the solution is to either save the complex $Var to a simpler one and use the simpler one, OR use a proper filter string. the following otta work ... `-Filter "Name -like '*$($Name.Text)'"`. note the outer double quotes and the inner singletons. ///// i cannot test that [no AD access], but it matches other samples.

Comment: To provide background information on @Lee_Dailey's helpful comment: It's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why that doesn't work, but you could make a temporary string to get around this.

```
$tmpStr = "*" + $Name.text + "*"
Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $tmpStr}
```

Comment: This is a viable workaround, but it's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375) altogether.