# Powershell Script to Get Files with Certain Date in String

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm building a powershell script to only grab files with a certain date in the string (yesterday's date) and display their names. But it doesn't seem to be going well. I've tried Googling but haven't found specifically help on what I'm trying to do:

```
$a = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')

$b = Get-ChildItem "E:\Export" -Filter {$_.Name -like '*'+$a.ToString()}

Get-ChildItem "E:\Export" -Filter *.txt |

Foreach-Object {

    If ($b -like $a)
    {
    Write-Host $b
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$a` **IS** already a string. You can't simply put a script block as a filter.

```
$a = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
$b = Get-ChildItem "E:\Export" | Where-Object BaseName -like "*$a*"
$b
```

or

```
$b = Get-ChildItem "E:\Export\*$a*"
```

Comment: That being said, `-Filter "*$a*"` should also work instead of the `Where-Object`.

Answer (score 3):

**td;dr**

```
$b = Get-ChildItem "E:\Export" -Filter ('*' + $a)
```

Or, using PowerShell's string expansion (interpolation):

```
$b = Get-ChildItem "E:\Export" -Filter "*$a"
```

---

`-Filter` parameter values:

- are *always* `[string]`-typed
- their specific *syntax* is *provider-dependent*

Since you're dealing with *files*, it is the `FileSystem` PS provider that interprets `-Filter`, and it expects a *wildcard expression* as an argument, as accepted by the underlying Windows API; the wildcard expression is implicitly matched against the file *name*.

Note:

- Typically - such as in this case - such wildcard expressions work the same as [PowerShell's own wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards), but the former have quirks in order to support legacy applications, while the latter offer additional features.
- No standard provider accepts *script blocks* with *arbitrary PowerShell code* as a `-Filter` arguments, despite their widespread - but misguided - use with the Active Directory provider - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

To perform arbitrary filtering of output objects via script blocks *in PowerShell code*, pipe to the `Where-Object` cmdlet, as shown in [LotPings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53787150/45375).

However, **if feasible, use of `-Filter` should always be the first choice**, because it filters *at the source*, meaning that the provider returns the already-filtered results to PowerShell (as opposed to having to filter the results after the fact, in PowerShell code), which **can greatly speed up operations**.