# Keeping Newlines in Powershell For Loop

Tags: powershell

I have a list of DisplayNames and I wan't to look up each of the SamAccountNames, but when I do I want to keep a blank line when there is no SamAccountName is found.  Right now when I run it against my list of 400 DisplayNames the output is only 350, but I don't know where those 50 in my list that are missing.  What I have right now is:

```
Get-Content C:\list.txt | ForEach-Object {(Get-ADUser -Filter {DisplayName -eq $_}).SamAccountName}
```

I've used a similar syntax with other commands that do produce blank lines, but as far as I can tell using *-Filter* seems to change it some how that causes the blank lines to no longer be present.

So, instead of something like this:

```
jonesb
williamsj

bakere
```

I get:

```
jonesb
williamsj
bakere
```

Comment: If you want to know which are not found I would look at a [pscustomobject] and if (Get-ADUser -Identity $_) {get-aduser $_ | select -expandproperty SamAccountName} else {“$($_) not found”}. Sorry about formatting, I am on mobile.

Comment: As an aside: It's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an `If` statement inside your `ForEach-Object` loop by capturing the results of the `Get-ADUser` call, and then outputting the samaccountname if the user was found, and outputting an empty string if it wasn't found.

```
Get-Content C:\list.txt | 
    ForEach-Object {
        If(($User=Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$_'")){
            $User.SamAccountName
        }else{
            ''
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

400 DisplayNames minus 350 SamAccountNames gives 10?

I'd prefer an output where you see the DisplayName a SamAccountName couldn't be evaluated for.

```
$Data = foreach ($DisplayName in (Get-Content C:\list.txt)){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DisplayName    = $DisplayName
        SamAccountName = (Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$DisplayName'").SamAccountName
    }
}
$Data | Out-GridView
$Data | Export-Csv C:\list.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Fixed my typo.  Yes, it should have been 50, not 10.

Answer (score 0):

First, an aside: It's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375), which is why the solution below uses a *string* argument.

---

- Using `Get-AdUser` with a `-Filter` argument that matches no users quietly returns "nothing" (effectively, `$null`), and, as a consequence, accessing the `.SamAccountName` property on that "nothing" returns `$null`.
- While such a `$null` *is* present in the output, it *doesn't print*; you can make it print - as an empty line - if you cast it to a *string*:

Therefore:

```
Get-Content C:\list.txt | ForEach-Object {
  [string] (Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq `"$_`"").SamAccountName
}
```

However, to provide context, consider outputting a `[pscustomobject]` instance in each iteration that includes the input display name, as shown in [LotPings' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55718340/45375).