# How to use variables in Powershell block / closure parameters

Tags: powershell, closures

This works beautifully:

```bsh
Get-Mailbox -Filter {DisplayName -like "Axel*"}
```

Now I want to re-use this in a function. Unfortunately, this construct horribly fails:

```bsh
> $name = "Axel*"
> Get-Mailbox -Filter {DisplayName -like $name}
```

I am no powershell god, but I think (!) I have figured out that the closure (I think the `{Displayname -eq ...}` is one) is evaluated on execution, which is *in* the `Get-Mailbox` cmdlet, where the variable is no longer available from the outer scope.

So my question is - how do I do that?

I explicitly do **not** want to do this, because it's about 50 times slower:

```bsh
Get-Mailbox | Where-Object DisplayName -like $name
```

Can anyone help me out here?

I found [a](https://medium.com/@pitermarx/powershell-closures-80f59fac3937) [couple](http://www.powertheshell.com/closure/) [of](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sergey_babkins_blog/2015/01/02/powershell-script-blocks-are-not-closures/) articles which go into detail, all of them seem to boil down to: "Just use `.GetNewClosure()`". That did not work for me:

```bsh
> $dname = "Axel*"
> Get-Mailbox -Filter {DisplayName -like $dname}.GetNewClosure()
[...still no effect...]
```

Comment: Did you try `Using:`? This can be used to reference a variable for readonly usage across thread boundaries. It even works in remote PS sessions. `Get-Mailbox -Filter {DisplayName -like $Using:name}`

Comment: Based on the [Get-Maxilbox] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) docu `-Filter` is of type `string` not of type `ScriptBlock`. Are you sure it works with `Get-Mailbox -Filter {DisplayName -like "Axel*"}`? From my point of view it has to be `Get-Mailbox -Filter ({DisplayName -like "Axel*"}).Invoke()`.

Comment: I've seen this issue before. Couldnt find the reason, I've assigned whole filter to a variable and it worked. ugly but works

`$name = "DisplayName -like 'Axel*'"`
`Get-Mailbox -Filter $name`

Comment: Please see this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075502/get-aduser-filter-will-not-accept-a-variable

**tl;dr**
`$dname = "Axel*"`
`Get-Mailbox -Filter "DisplayName -like '$name'"`

Comment: @Moerwald - when I try to do `$Using:dname` I get "invalid filter syntax" error. Teh 2nd one also does not work :(

Comment: @TeslaGreat - that actually works!! :D Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The only sad thing is that I still don't know how to do this with closures/script blocks/whatever this is. But it solves my problem :D

Comment: @flypenguin why do you want to use curly brackets? The link I provided says exactly the opposite - you should "feed" the filter as string :) I didn't know myself why it doesn't work until I tried to help you. Glad that we both benefited from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Tesla Great above - this solution actually works:

```bsh
> $dname = "Axel*"
> $full_filter = "DisplayName -like '$dname'"
> Get-Mailbox -Filter $full_filter
```

And it IS as fast as it should be.

Awesome :)