# Get Samaccountname from display name into .csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I have a .csv file with **displayName** and then the display names of the users.

I am running the following code, but the returned .csv file is blank 0KB. I've spent hours on this and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

(I've even tried switching the displayName to "DisplayName" but that doesn't work)

```
Get-Content C:\Scripts\displaynames.txt | ForEach {
   Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$user'" -Properties Name, SamAccountName, City, co, DistinguishedName | 
Select Name,SamAccountName, City, co, DistinguishedName
} | Export-CSV -path C:\output\paininthebut.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I just need a simple return of the **displayName = samaccountname**

Comment: where is $user coming from?  Should that be a value parsed out of the input csv file?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, The user is coming from a csv file with the format of lastname, firstname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is in fact a Csv file with a header for each column,
and `displayname` is one of them - then use `Import-Csv` to get the data.

`ForEach-Object` uses the variable `$_` or alternatively `$PSItem` to assign the currently iterated row of data with the columns as properties.

So change to:

```
Import-Csv C:\Scripts\displaynames.txt | ForEach {
   Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.DisplayName)'" -Properties Name, SamAccountName, City, co, DistinguishedName | 
Select Name,SamAccountName, City, co, DistinguishedName
} | Export-CSV -path C:\output\paininthebut.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Read this helpful answer on the issue of `Get-AdUser`and `-filter` from [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/6811411)

Comment: Alright, this at least returned some of the names. Now the problem seems to be that I am only getting some of the names. My input file has 600+ names and the return file only has 43  names. I checked the spelling because that would definitely be a problem and the spelling is correct. It also shows that there are only two errors not 550+. Any ideas? I used your script:

Comment: Import-Csv C:\Scripts\7231employeesJM.txt | ForEach {
   Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.DisplayName)'" -Properties Name, SamAccountName | 
Select Name,SamAccountName
} | Export-CSV -path C:\output\paininthebut.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: I'm a bit confused if the csv file does **not** have a column `DisplayName` but `lastname`, `firstname` - how is the DisplayName build from these?

Comment: Hi LotPings, it does have that column. It has the following format: displayName in cell A1 and starting with A2 it has the users lastname, firstname which is how our display names are formatted. The script is just now only returning only a small portion of the names. I can't figure out why its not returning more than 40 out of 600+

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, I figured out the problem. The reason the input file was only returning some names is because the some of the names had spaces. For example
Doe, John was written as 
Doe , John 
with an extra space between the last letter of the last name and comma. To get just the displayName I used the following script:
Import-Csv C:\Scripts\inputfile.txt | ForEach {
   Get-ADUser -Filter "displayName -eq '$($_.displayName)'" -Properties Name, SamAccountName | 
Select Name,SamAccountName
} | Export-CSV -path C:\output\outputfile.csv -NoTypeInformation