# Get samaccountname from display name - but with extras

Tags: powershell, active-directory

First time poster but site has helped me so much in the past.

We are an MSP and regularly get requests from clients to pull various details off a list of users they send us. Unfortunately though their lists rarely (if ever) contain any unique identifiers for AD such as samAccountName or even e-mail.

So typically I only get their first and last names, job titles etc. and use a slight variation on the below to try and get the required samAccountNames to work in batch modify scripts.

[Get Samaccountname from display name into .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484733/get-samaccountname-from-display-name-into-csv)

The problem comes (and caused a big headache recently) when I try to put that output back into a table to line up with the displaynames. As if the script can't find the displayname it just moves onto the next one in the list and puts the samAccountName directly below the last one it found. making it out of line with the displayname column I've put it beside.

My question is is there something I can add to the below script that when an error occurs it simply inputs **null** or similar into the samAccountName output csv so I could spot that easily in an excel sheet.

Similarly some users have multiple accounts like an admin and non-admin account with the same display name but different samAccountName so it pulls both of them, which is less of a problem but also if there was any way to have the script let me know when that happens? That would be super useful for future.

```
Import-Module activedirectory
$displayname = @()
$names = get-content "c:\temp\users.csv"
foreach ($name in $names) {


$displaynamedetails = Get-ADUser -filter { DisplayName -eq $name } -server "domain.local"| Select name,samAccountName

$displayname += $displaynamedetails

}

$displayname | Export-Csv "C:\temp\Samaccountname.csv"
```

Comment: Your users.csv file is really just a single-column list of displaynames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem lies in that you rely on Get-ADUser to provide you with user objects and when it doesn't you have gaps in your output.  You instead need to create an object for every name/line in your "csv" regardless of whether `Get-ADUser` finds anything.

```
Get-Content 'c:\temp\users.csv' | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $name = $_
        $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$name'" -Server 'domain.local' 

        # Create object for every user in users.csv even if Get-ADUser returns nothing
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            DisplayName    = $name                     # this will be populated with name from the csv file
            SamAccountName = $adUser.SamAccountName    # this will be empty if $adUser is empty
        }
    } | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\Samaccountname.csv'
```

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel, I will try this next opportunity I get!