# Powershell - Unable to pass variable to commandlet

Tags: powershell, variables

When I'm holding a variable and passing it to a commandlet I am getting inconsistent results. Maybe I am just plain using variables in powershell incorrectly? If there were a way to see exactly the line of code my Visual Studio Code was sending at runtime that would be helpful.

My code returns a $null object when executing those first two filters. I've confirmed that $username actually does contain the string "userLoginName" but it doesn't seem to pass to the Get-ADUser commandlet correctly.

```
PS C:\> $username = "userLoginName"

PS C:\> Get-ADUser -Filter {SAMAccountName -eq "$($username)"}
PS C:\> Get-ADUser -Filter {SAMAccountName -eq "$username"}
PS C:\> Get-ADUser -Filter {SAMAccountName -eq "userLoginName"}
```

Why is it that only the third -filter command runs successfully? The first two return $null, not a UserNotFound kind of exception or anything. What am I doing wrong here? Do I just have no concept of how to use variables in powershell (yes)? Sorry for being a noob, but thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075502/get-aduser-filter-will-not-accept-a-variable). The AD calls' `-Filter` parameter doesn't like taking in string variables as part of a ScriptBlock for some reason (you can read the post more for more info). But passing `-Filter` as a String should work.

`Get-ADUser -Filter "SAMAccountName -eq '$username'"`

Alternatively, if you're just wanting to lookup an AD user with the SAMAccountName, you can just do `Get-ADUser -Identity $username`. That's probably easier. The benefit (or sometimes the consequence) of using the `-Filter` parameter is that, like you discovered, it won't throw an exception if a user is not found. If you use the `-Identity` parameter, it WILL throw an exception if a user is not found.