# Problem placing a variable in a cmdlet with "-eq"

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, exchange-server

I am trying to do something very simple in Exchange 2019 powershell, but for the life of me I cannot seem to get my head around a simple variable placement. The issue has nothing to do with Exchange, just pure PS.

I need to execute the cmdlet

```
New-AddressList "XX Users" -RecipientFilter {((CustomAttribute2 -eq "XX") -and (RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox'))}
```

which is fine, but I want to replace "XX Users" and "XX" with variables.

I can replace "XX Users" by saying something like

```
$var1 = "XX Users" (this actually works)
$var2 = "XX" (does not work)
```

so I get

```
New-AddressList $var1 -RecipientFilter {((CustomAttribute2 -eq $var2) -and (RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox'))}
```

for the life of me that `$var2` does not insert the correct value for the `-eq`. I have tried numerous combinations, including using single quote, double quote, where object, moving braces around and I have gotten nowhere. It either takes it as literal or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`-RecipientFilter` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/email-addresses-and-address-books/new-addresslist?view=exchange-ps#parameters) is `[string]`-typed, which means that the *literal* contents of the script block you pass - everything between the opening `{` and the closing `}` - is passed as a value.

That is, *no* interpolation of variable references such as `$var2` takes place, so unless `New-AddressList` itself actively performs that interpolation by accessing the caller's variables, `$var2` will be used *verbatim*, which is not your intent.

This sounds like the same problem as with AD (Active Directory) filters - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375) (except that the latter actually *do* interpolate *simple* variable references, but not *expressions* such as `$var2.Name`, which is why it's better not to rely on that).

**As in the AD case, the best approach is to construct your `-RecipientFilter` argument as a *string*, specifically as an [*expandable string* (`"..."`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) in which you can embed variable *values***:

```
# Construct the filter as an *expandable string*.
# Note that $var2 is instantly replaced by its value, so
# you still need quoting around it.
# The assumption is that $var2's value doesn't contain single quotes itself.
$filterString = "((CustomAttribute2 -eq '$var2') -and (RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox'))"

New-AddressList $var1 -RecipientFilter $filterString
```

<sup>If `$var2` may contain `'` chars. itself, replace `$var2` with an expression that *escapes* these; if `New-AddressList` expects the same escaping as PowerShell itself - i.e. *doubling* `'` chars. - replace `$var2` with `$($var2 -replace "'", "''")`.</sup>

---

Curiously, as of this writing, the [official help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/email-addresses-and-address-books/new-addresslist?view=exchange-ps) actively recommends the `{ ... }` syntax without stating its fundamental limitation, and all example commands show filters with literals only.
[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/4206) was created to address that.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was helpful, @NimaKamkar; my pleasure. I find it baffling that the official documentation actively recommends the `{ ... }` syntax without even mentioning its limitations.

Comment: My pleasure, @NimaKamkar; thanks for the feedback - let's hope the GitHub issue will trigger documentation updates.