# PowerShell REGEX in ForEach-Object

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to obtain the machine name from the user name which makes up part of the machine name, using PowerShell and Active Directory.
Our PC naming convention is like this: XXXZZZ01BLOGGSJ where the last characters after the last number is the username of the PC owner.

I know that to derive the user name from the PC name using REGEX, I can do this:

```
"XXXZZZ01BLOGGSJ" -replace '\D*\d*(\w*)', '$1'
```

(result is BLOGGSJ)

What I need to be able to do is derive the computer name from the username via Active directory and have tried this and various version of this:

```
"BloggsJ" | % { Get-ADComputer -Server blahblah.com -Filter {name -like "xxxzzz*"} | ? "$_.Name -replace '\D*\d*(\w*)', '$1' -eq '$_'" } | select  Name
```

This fails with no result and I am struggling to find the correct method of doing this, any help please?

Comment: Do you have to pipe the name into it? It'd be simpler to do something like `$UserName = 'BloggsJ'; Get-ADComputer -Server blahblah.com -Filter "name -like 'xxxzzz'" | Where {$_.Name -match $UserName} | Select -Expand Name`

Comment: As an aside: It's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Comment: Thanks @TheMadTechnician - I need to pipe it due to bulk resolutions. I will try to adapt your meth using foreach-object

Comment: I managed it like this: $UserList | %{$UserName = $_ ; Get-ADComputer -Server blahblah.com -Filter "name -like 'xxxzzz*'" | ? {$_.Name -match $UserName}} | Select -Expand Name       Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: You might find your script performs better if you capture the result of Get-ADComputer into a variable so you only query Active Directory once. At present you're running your AD query for every user, but almost certainly getting the same list of computers each time.