# Default condition of Switch parameter never gets triggered

Tags: powershell

I have a switch statement inside a function like so:

```
function SomeFunc {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [switch]$History
    )
    Process {
    switch ($PSBoundParameters.keys) {
        'History' {$PSBoundParameters.keys}
        Default {write-host "No Parameters used"} 
        }
    }
}
```

If I invoke `SomeFunc -History` "History" gets printed, as expected.
but for the life of me, I cannot get the `default` condition to trigger, I am expecting "No Parameters used" to print when I invoke only "SomeFunc"

Comment: `AutomationNull.Value` does not get enumerated

Comment: True, @SantiagoSquarzon, but here it is actually an _empty collection_ that is the problem, and I think it's worth discussing the non-obvious enumeration behavior of `switch` in general, so I took the liberty of reopening this question.

Comment: @mklement0 good clarification, I do believe this exact question has been asked before tho

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I didn't look too hard, but if you can find a bona fide duplicate, we can close this question again; I just searched my own notes again and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59402280/45375), which may qualify as a duplicate, though it's focused mostly on AutomationNull and mentions the empty-collection case only in passing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Because `$PSBoundParameters.Keys` is an *empty collection* when no arguments are passed, the `switch` statement's body is never entered.
- Use `$PSBoundParameters.Count -eq 0` to detect if no parameters were passed.

---

It isn't obvious, but **the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement
*enumerates* its input, just like the pipeline does**.

That is, if you provide an *enumerable* object to `switch`, the *enumerated elements* are processed, *one by one*.
Typical examples of enumerables are arrays or collections, though *not* hashtables. See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530467/45375) for details on what PowerShell considers enumerable.

It follows that *if there is nothing to enumerate*, no processing takes place at all - not even the `default` branch is entered.

In short: **Any *empty* enumerable causes the `switch` statement's body to be *skipped***, notably with:

- an **empty array or collection** (one without elements), such as the empty [`` [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[string, object]] ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keys) instance that the [automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters)'s `.Key` property returns when *no* parameters are bound.
- a call to a **command that produces *no output***

  - The reason is that PowerShell represents the no-output case with a special object sometimes called "AutomationNull", which can be thought of as an "enumerable `$null`"; that is, in an enumeration context it behaves like an *empty collection* rather than `$null` - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30016949/45375) for details.

Two simple examples in which a `switch` statement's body is skipped:

```bash
# An empty array has nothing to enumerate -> body is not entered.
switch (@()) { 
  default { 'Never get here!' }
}

# Ditto for a command that produces no output.
switch ((Get-ChildItem -Filter *NoSuchFiles*)) { 
  default { 'Never get here!' }
}
```

Comment: What a pitfall! Thank goodness you decided to elaborate on it, you just know some of us folks would be scratching our heads on this again later. Thanks allot!