# Powershell... 'enabled eq $true' vs where {$_.Enabled -eq $true}

Tags: powershell

I know very very little about powershell.

I'm wondering if anyone can point me at what I need to learn about to explain the following:

```
PS C:\Users\username> (Get-Aduser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true').count
1234
PS C:\Users\username> (Get-Aduser -filter * | where {$_.Enabled -eq $true }).count
13
```

They read pretty similar... ? What is 'Enabled' and how can it be different to the `$_` which I read refers to the 'current object on the pipeline' which I assume is iterated through with the 'where'.

Thanks!

Comment: Both queries will yield the same result, 2nd will take a lot longer than the first one. $_ is single iteration of users that was retrieved being filtered on your condition. `.Enabled` as you already know is the property of User's object., Point to note, you might come across exceptions if the dataset is too large

Comment: The results are different, though, as you can see above?

Comment: There must be something odd about what's in our AD - the verbatim queries in my question produce the numbers that you see on the same machine in the same powershell window.

Comment: try this in powershell... `$true -eq "ANYTHING" = true`.

Comment: @Jawad Irrelevant, because it assumes that the string you pass to `-Filter` is PowerShell code that is evaluated by PowerShell rules in any way. It is not. `Get-ADUser` parses that string internally, translates it into an LDAP filter string, and sends that to the server. What PowerShell would do with the same code does not apply here.

Answer (score 4):

In general - This

```bash
Get-Aduser -Filter "something -eq 'some value'"
```

sends the filter to the server (i.e. the domain controller), and the server only returns the matching users, whereas this

```bash
Get-Aduser -filter *
```

gets *all* users from the server, and filters them in a second step inside the script (using `where`).

Obviously the first approach is much more efficient, even if the result is the same.

---

As for the `Enabled` check, things are a bit more complicated. User objects in AD do not actually have an `Enabled` property - that property is added on the client side. Which means that you can't pass `Enabled -eq $true` to the server, it would not know what to do with that.

AD user account objects have [the `userAccountControl` property](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/305144/how-to-use-useraccountcontrol-to-manipulate-user-account-properties) which collects all kinds of flags:

> ```
> SCRIPT            0x0001   1
> ACCOUNTDISABLE    0x0002   2
> HOMEDIR_REQUIRED  0x0008   8
> LOCKOUT           0x0010  16
> PASSWD_NOTREQD    0x0020  32
> ```

and quite a few more. An account is disabled when flag `2` is set. You can query the server specifically if this flag is set by using an LDAP filter:

```bash
# all disabled users
Get-ADUser -LdapFilter "(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"

# all NOT disabled users
Get-ADUser -LdapFilter "(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
```

This is a bit unwieldy but it's the way LDAP does it. *(The `:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:` represents the "bitwise AND" operator in LDAP. They somehow did not make a simpler symbol for it.)*

With this filter, the filtering actually happens on the server side again, which means it should be significantly faster than the alternative, especially when there are many user accounts in AD.

I don't think there is a way to express this particular thing in the "friendly" `-Filter` syntax of `Get-ADUser`, but other filters would work server-side

```bash
# all users whose first name starts with an A
Get-ADUser -Filter "givenName -like 'A*'"
```

---

What `Get-ADUser` does internally is, it parses the `-Filter` string, and builds an LDAP filter from that, because the LDAP filter syntax is the only thing the server understands:

The "PowerShell-style" filter `givenName -like 'A*'` will be translated to the LDAP filter `(givenName=A*)`.

But it appears when trying that with `Enabled -eq $true`, something goes wrong inside `Get-ADUser`, it seems to ignore it entirely, probably because it's not smart enough to translate that into `(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))`. And so the LDAP filter stays empty and the server returns *all* accounts.

This is the reason why I tend to write LDAP filters from the start. It's not too hard to learn, more versatile than the PowerShell syntax, faster than client-side filtering and it's sent to the server as-is, nothing messes with it beforehand.

Comment: I've checked with our AD, and `Get-Aduser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true'` simply returns *all* accounts. I've explained why in the extensions to my answer. It would be better if `Get-ADUser` threw an error (*"could not interpret filter string"* or something like that), but it doesn't. It's just one of the many PowerShell quirks to be aware of.

Comment: Sorry I'm late, but your answer was referred to in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62460474/4749264). Per the comment I tested -Filter `'Enabled -eq $true'` and it worked fine.  I got the same results as with `Where`. I then did `-Filter *` and got more results.  I grouped the results to confirm the difference was enabled vs. disabled. PoSh 5.1 2k8 FFL separate tests against 2k8, 12 & 19 DCs.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Steven, given that `Enabled` == `userAccountControl` is a _bit field_, the question is what comparing it to `$true` yields  - assuming it even gets successfully translated into an LDAP filter - Tomalak seems to think it doesn't, implying a bug (I have no way to verify). If it does - perhaps dependent on version? - is it smart enough to translate the `-eq $true` part into the bitwise AND test in LDAP syntax, as shown in the answer?

Comment: Per the filter syntax described in [about_Active_Directory_Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)), the following _should_ work - and I'd be curious to know if it does: `(Enabled -band 2) -eq 0` (there's also a warning to avoid bit-wise operators for performance reasons, but that would equally apply to direct formulation in LDAP syntax). Is there a way to see what LDAP filter a `-Filter` argument is translated to, say with `-Verbose`?

Comment: @mklement0 Short of looking at the implementing source code, I'd probably resort to watching the actual network traffic with Wireshark - although that could be difficult on an encrypted connection. Nice tip with the `-band` though, I didn't know.

Comment: @mklement you could enable elevated LDAP logging on a domain controller, which should log the translated LDAP query.  I believe it's a registry value.  That would be a lot easier than a packet capture.  If I have time today I will try it out.

Comment: Please see my answer, which is largely based on Santiago Squarzon's findings; it also points to a Gist with a function that allows diagnosing what LDAP filter a `-Filter` argument translates to. /cc @Steven.

Answer (score 1):

Preface:

- Based on the explanation below, I would expect `Get-Aduser -Filter * | where {$_.Enabled -eq $true }`<sup>[1]</sup>  to return the *same* number of users as `Get-Aduser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true'` - albeit much more slowly.
- Credit for the findings below belongs to [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77413746/45375) and his sleuthing.

---

To complement [Tomalak's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59952927/45375):

**Using the Boolean `Enabled` property in a `-Filter` argument *should* work as intended** and is unquestionably preferable to post-filtering, for the reasons explained in Tomalak's answer:

- When the PowerShell AD provider translates the PowerShell-*like* filter expressions - see [about_ActiveDirectoryFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)) - passed to the `-Filter` parameter into the *equivalent LDAP query* behind the scenes, it does two things:

  - It translates the PowerShell-like operators such as `-eq` into the LDAP operators such as `=`
  - It translates the property names *as known in PowerShell* - e.g. `Enabled` - to the *underlying LDAP display names* - e.g., `userAccountControl`, based on [this mapping](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx)
  - You can **see the normally hidden results of this translation** via the **`Convert-AdFilter` function** from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/indented-automation/66e07bc76fdb6cf0be6743ed0b24575c).
- This translation *is* smart enough to translate the *Boolean* operation into the equivalent *bitwise* AND operation:

  - That is:

    - `-Filter 'Enabled -eq $true'` (and variations thereof) properly translates to LDAP filter `(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))`
    - `-Filter 'Enabled -eq $false'` (and variations thereof) properly translates to LDAP filter `(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)`, as shown in this screenshot: [image: Convert-ADFilter]
    - On a syntax note: `-Filter` does *not* support *implicit* Boolean operations the way that PowerShell does; that is, the following do *not* work:

      - <del>`-Filter '-not Enabled'`</del>
      - <del>`-Filter 'Enabled'`</del>
      - This is but one of the pitfalls associated with the `-Filter` parameter syntax; see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375) for more, and the next point.
- That said, you may still choose to use [LDAP filters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) *directly* and  pass them to the `-LDAPFilter` parameter instead, to rule out any uncertainty over what `-Filter` expressions translate to.

  - Do note that this filter language is fundamentally different, however, and, in addition to learning its different syntax and operator names, you'll also need to know the property-name mapping discussed above.

---

<sup>[1] which can be simplified to `Get-AdUser -Filter * | where { $_.Enabled }` or even, using [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax), `Get-AdUser -Filter * | where Enabled`.</sup>