# Partial Replace in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, replace

Let's say we have the following code

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} -properties * | sort Surname| FT GivenName, Surname, description
```

It produces:

```
 GivenName      Surname           description                          
 ---------      ---------         ------- -----------                                              
 Tom            Abbott            AccountingSystems 
 Tim            Baker             AccountingSystems 
 Tyler          Cabot             AccountingSystems
```

I need to put a space in between 'Accounting' and 'System'

I thought this would work:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} -properties *
% {
   $Description = $.replace("Accounting","Accounting ")
   Set-ADUser = -Description $Description
  }
```

But... it does not.

Comment: This looks wrong... Maybe more like this `$_.Description.replace("Accounting","Accounting ") `

Comment: As an aside: If [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59952927/45375) is correct, `Enabled -eq $false` doesn't actually work as intended. Does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I would recommend you look into,

1. There is no such variable as $. When you are looping through items with ForEach, you have to use $_ (with underscore)
2. You cannot assign value to a cmdlet (Set-ADUser = ).
3. You use | then % (not % | )

Try this,

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} -properties Description | % {
   if ($_.Description) {
       $description = $_.Description.replace("Accounting","Accounting ") 
       Set-ADUser $_ -Description $Description
   } # else description is null.
}
```

[Documentation for Set-ADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser?view=win10-ps)
[Documentation for ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7)