# Filter enabled AD users from CSV file

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I have a script to import a list of users and want to check if any of these users are disabled. I did try to run the script below but it doesn't filter the users in the CSV file it filters everyone in the entire organization. any suggestions would be appreciated.  displayname and SIP address in one of the headers in the CSV file if needed to use the header.

```
Import-CSV -Path .\Piscataway-+1732.csv  | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq '$true'"  | select Enabled,EmailAddress,SamAccountName
} | Export-CSV .\results77.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You're not using the data you imported from your CSV file. You'd need to use the pipeline variable `$_` for that. An alternative would be to use `Search-ADAccount –AccountDisabled –UsersOnly` to fin all disabled users and compare this list with `Compare-Object` against the data from your CSV file.

Comment: Maybe try `Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.DisplayName)' -and Enabled -eq '$false'"`

Comment: I don't know if their's a quirk with `Get-ADUser`'s parameters but if you pipe to it and specify the `-Filter` parameter it seems to filter against the whole domain.  My preference would be to get only the users specified in the csv file.  Noting that we should try to move the filter left, but in this case doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Aside from the issues covered in [Steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62460734/45375), `'Enabled -eq $true'` is _syntactically_ the better way to formulate your `-Filter`, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59952927/45375) suggests that you cannot actually filter by the `Enabled` property.

Comment: @mklement0 I can't read your work without complimenting you, in this case your ability to correlate answers is terrific.  It really makes the conversation more robust.  In practice I haven't found any issues with `-Filter 'Enabled -eq $true'`, and I use it a lot!  However, it wouldn't be the first time something went unnoticed, so I went ahead and retested.  I got the same results from `-Filter` as I I did post-filtering with `Where`.  I got more results with `-Filter *`.  This seems to say that `-Filter 'Enabled -eq $true'` works!

Comment: Thank you, @Steven, both for the compliment and the clarification. I personally do not have access to AD, so I had to believe the linked answer. Could you please leave feedback there? The answer's author states in a comment that `Enabled -eq $true` returns _all_ accounts for him, whether enabled or not. Was this a bug in older versions that has been fixed?

Comment: @mklement0 - Please see the final Script below. I did use Steven logic and change the script so it gives me the result I needed 'Import-CSV -Path "c:\temp\export1221.csv"  | 
Select-Object @{Label = 'Enabled'; Expression = { ( Get-ADUser $_.samAccountName ).Enabled } } ,samAccountName |
Export-CSV -Path "c:\temp\Output88.csv" -NoTypeInformation
 '  Th results look this this Enabled samAccountName
TRUE samAccountName1
TRUE samAccountName2
FALSE samAccountName3
TRUE samAccountName4

Comment: @mklement0 I did promptly post a comment on that other answer.  Sorry I forgot to mention here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues:

1. You are piping From `Import-Csv` to `ForEach-Object`.  So `Get-ADUser` doesn't really know you are piping it input objects.
2. `Get-ADUser`'s `-Identity` parameter is by value, not by property name. so you need to echo the appropriate column to send it down the pipe.
3. If you pipe and use the `-Filter` parameter the filter is going to apply to the whole domain.  It's not going to limit the filter to what you piped in.
4. If you want the email address to be output you have to tell `Get-ADUser` to retrieve it.

Try something like this:

```
Import-CSV -Path .\Piscataway-+1732.csv  | 
ForEach-Object{ $_.samAccountName }
Get-ADUser -Properties mail | 
Where-Object{ $_.Enabled }
Select-Object Enabled,mail,SamAccountName  | 
Export-CSV .\results77.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

> Note: The Property for the email address is "mail".
>
> Note: Since we don't have a sample of the CSV file the above example
> assumes there's a column names samAccountName.

Now, if you want the output to come from the CSV file but validate it according to the user's status in AD we have to change the approach.  As always there are several ways to do this.

Example 1:

```
Import-CSV -Path "c:\temp\test.csv"  | 
Select-Object @{Label = 'Enabled'; Expression = { ( Get-ADUser $_.samAccountName ).Enabled } },EmailAddress,samAccountName |
Export-CSV -Path "c:\temp\Output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This again assumes the column name (samAccountName).  It also assumes there is not already an "enabled" column.  So we are adding a property called enabled that we're getting via Get-ADUser. Then finally re-exporting to Csv.

Example 2:

```
$CsvData = Import-CSV -Path "c:\temp\test.csv"

$EnabledUsers = 
( 
    $CsvData | 
    ForEach-Object{ $_.samAccountName } |
    Get-ADUser |
    Where-Object{ $_.Enabled }
).samAccountName

$CsvData | 
Where-Object{ $EnabledUsers -contains $_.samAccountName } |
Select-Object @{Label = 'Enabled'; Expression = { $true } },EmailAddress,samAccountName |
Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\Output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Example 1 is great for small jobs but too many individual calls to `Get-ADUser` might be slow for larger runs.  In this example Import the CSV data once.  Then use it to get a flat list of those entries that are enabled in AD.  Once you have that you can use the `-contains` operator to check if the account is enabled.  Once again there's a little extra work to add the "Enabled" property.

This should give you a general idea.  There are probably a dozen more ways to do this, but hopefully this give you a good idea of what has to happen.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Steven, I change the header of my CSV file from SIP to MAIL and mad sure that excel column has the mail(email) and no space in each cell, but I got this error below: 
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.
At line:2 char:1 + Get-ADUser -Properties mail |
+ CategoryInfo  : InvalidData: (@{LineUri=tel:+...fe-den.hds.com}:PSObject) [Get-ADUser],ParameterBindingValidationException+FullyQualifiedErrorIdParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser. Pleae advise

Comment: Once you pipe to Get-ADUser each subsequent cmdlet is consuming output from Get-ADUser NOT the csv file.  That said I think I better understand what you're trying to do.  Let me cook up another example.  A sample of the CSV data would be helpful!

Comment: The `-Identity` parameter is by value.  I already corrected the examples.  Added additional examples for what I "think" you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, Steven this is the only version that works at the end. thank you so much for all your assistance:'Import-CSV -Path "c:\temp\export1221.csv"  | 
Select-Object @{Label = 'Enabled'; Expression = { ( Get-ADUser $_.samAccountName ).Enabled } } samAccountName |
Export-CSV -Path "c:\temp\Output3.csv" -NoTypeInformation
'