# Filtering multiple values

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to filter out a couple employees using their specific EmployeeNumber in addition to making sure the user object actually has an employeenumber and is enabled.

Any better way to write this? and actually have it work as the users are still coming through.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(employeeNumber -ne $false) -and (employeeNumber -ne 000614) 
    -and (employeeNumber -ne 000864) -and (employeeNumber -ne 001195) 
    -and (employeeNumber -ne 001200) -and (employeeNumber -ne 001201) 
    -and (employeeNumber -ne 000628) -and (employeeNumber -ne 000742) 
    -and (employeeNumber -ne 000041) -and (employeeNumber -ne 001225) 
    -and (employeeNumber -ne 001181) -and (employeeNumber -ne 001074)
    -and (employeeNumber -ne 001203) -and (employeeNumber -ne 001198)
    -and (employeeNumber -ne 001208) -and (employeeNumber -ne 001224)
    -and (employeeNumber -ne 001207) -and (employeeNumber -ne 001199)
    -and (employeeNumber -ne 001210) -and (employeeNumber -ne 001214)
    -and (employeeNumber -ne 001220) -and (employeeNumber -ne 001212)
    -and (employeeNumber -ne 001213) -and (employeeNumber -ne 001221)
    -and (employeeNumber -ne 000036) -and (employeeNumber -ne 000589) 
    -and (employeeNumber -ne 099998) -and (enabled -ne $false)}
```

Comment: As an aside: While seductively convenient, the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments is conceptually problematic and can lead to misconceptions - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Answer (score 2):

> Any better way to write this?

Not really, the filtering approach is correct. What you could automate is building the filter string from an array of values. I personally use `LDAPFilter` here, it's easier to build the filter string.

```bash
$toExclude = 000864, 001200, 000628, 000041, 001181, 001203 # etc, more values can be added here

$filter = -join @(
    '(&'                                                  # AND, all conditions must be met
        '(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)' # Enabled objects
        '(employeeNumber=*)'                              # employeeNumber is not null
        $toExclude | ForEach-Object {                     # employeeNumber is not equal to
            "(!employeeNumber=$_)"                        # any of the values in $toExclude
        }
    ')'                                                   # close AND
)

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter
```

Comment: Regarding the use of the `enabled` property in `-Filter` arguments: if you have insights about what is discussed in the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59952927/45375, please share them there.

Comment: @mklement0 you're looking to know what `"enabled -eq '$true'"` translates to with the AD Filter API?

Comment: Yes (as well as `'enabled -ne $true'` / `'enabled -eq $false'`, to be safe) _and_ it would be good to know how to generally monitor what LDAP filters `-Filter` arguments translate to behind the scenes.

Comment: @mklement0 you can get them thru reflection using https://gist.github.com/indented-automation/66e07bc76fdb6cf0be6743ed0b24575c // all variations translates properly to their LDAP equivalent. I agree with Tomalak too, `-Filter` can fail sometimes or it doesnt properly translate, LDAP syntax is always better.

Comment: Thanks for that helpful link. I understand your preference to work directly with LDAP filters, and I can see the appeal of that approach. However, given that use of `-Filter` enables a more PowerShell-_like_ experience and given the predominant use of `-Filter`, I'm trying to get a definitive answer on whether querying the `enabled` property via `-Filter` _robustly_ translates into the necessary bitwise operation required on the server side. One of the examples in the linked repo implies that it _does_. Can you confirm that? (I have no way of trying this myself.)

Comment: @mklement0 yeah, for sure it properly translates to their LDAP equivalents. I dont have access to my lab rn but can share a screenshot later

Comment: @mklement0 see: https://i.imgur.com/4jUBxd7.png

Comment: @mklement0 im not sure what you mean, those 2 are not valid expressions for that api, they would produce an exception

Comment: Note that I'm flying blind here, and it is the _somewhat_ PowerShell-like syntax that keeps causing confusion. Your screenshot implies that while `-Filter 'enabled -eq $true'` works to find _enabled_ accounts, `-Filter 'enabled -eq $false'` to find _disabled_ ones does _not_, as it seemingly translates to the _same_ LDAP query, right? So the question is: what `-Filter` argument can be used to find _disabled_ accounts?

Comment: @mklement0 the screenshot shows that the filter is being correctly translated, all variations are translated to `(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)` to find disabled accounts. the filter to find enabled accounts is the same but negated in ldap syntax: `(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)`. I see that in comments Tomalak states that the filter returns all accounts which is not correct. the filter works properly with all its variations. this gives a better perspective https://i.imgur.com/SR6pded.png

Comment: Thanks -  I got confused about enabled vs. disabled. I encourage you to leave feedback on Tomalak's answer and/or post a definitive answer there. Let me know if you'd rather I do the latter.

Comment: @mklement0 feel free to do it and use the screenshots if needed

Comment: Thanks - I've posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77449040/45375). I'd appreciate it if you could check it for accuracy.

Comment: @mklement0 yep, looks good!