# Get-ADuser -server xxyy -filter {} doesn't work in a For loop

Tags: powershell, for-loop, active-directory

Been a while since I posted, but i've hit a road-block which an annoying issue

I have a need to scan all of the companies domains for user accounts based on full name, as is FIRST LAST

The same code works fine when running a get-aduser -identity -server domain.name, but using

Get-aduser -filter -server doesn't work inside a For loop, and I'm not sure why!

Here's the code:

```
$AllDomains = (Get-ADForest).domains

Function Check-ADUser {
    Param(
    $FullName,    
    $ADList
    )

    $ADUserArray = @()

    ForEach ($SubDomain in $ADList) {

        write-host "Checking for $FullName on $SubDomain ..."

        $UserADDomain = Get-ADUser -Server $SubDomain -Filter {(Name -eq $Fullname)} -properties *  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select @{n="DomainName"; e={($_.CanonicalName -split '/')[0]}} `
        | Select-Object DomainName -ExpandProperty DomainName        

    } #ForEach $Domain
```

The results return black

Here's the code that work fine:

```
$AllDomains = (Get-ADForest).domains

Function Check-ADUser {
    Param(
    $FullName,    
    $ADList
    )

    $ADUserArray = @()

    ForEach ($SubDomain in $ADList) {

        write-host "Checking for $FullName on $SubDomain ..."

        $UserADDomain = Get-ADUser -Server $SubDomain -Identity $userName -properties *  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select @{n="DomainName"; e={($_.CanonicalName -split '/')[0]}} `
        | Select-Object DomainName -ExpandProperty DomainName        

    } #ForEach $Domain
```

The function is called via a for loop against each user as such

```
$Users = @"
Rocky Balboa
Bruce Willis
Gene Simmons
Liz Phair
Steven Segal
"@ | ForEach {$_.Split([String[]]"`r`n",[StringSplitOPtions]::None)}

$outarray = @()

ForEach ($user in $Users) {        

    $aa = Check-ADUser -FullName $User -ADList $AllDomains

}
```

The only real difference in the code within the function, is the use the -filter instead of -identity on the get-aduser cmdlet

What's odd, is that if I run the code outside of the for loop, it works! I'm thinking it's a Powershell gotcha! any help appreciated :-)

Owen

Comment: While seductively convenient, it's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Comment: Please show us what is in `$FullName`, because you don't use that in the second example. Trying to identify a user by the Name property is asking for trouble. Better filter on `SamAccountName`, `EmailAddress`, `UserPrincipalName`, `DistinguishedName` or even `SID`, because these properties are/should be unique within the domain. As aside, it is bad practice to use `Properties *`. This pulls out ALL properties, where in your code you don't even need any user properties at all, except the one you are filtering on plus the `CanonicalName`

Comment: Hi Theo
I've updated my original post

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter statement like this,

If you are interested in performance, limit the properties to canonicalName instead of *.

After reading the last part of the docs, I think removing the ( ) within curly braces should resolve your issue as well.

```
$UserADDomain = Get-ADUser -Server $SubDomain -Filter "Name -eq '$Fullname'" -properties *  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select @{n="DomainName"; e={($_.CanonicalName -split '/')[0]}}

if ($null -ne $UserADDomain) {
  return $UserADDomain
}
```

[See Microsoft docs on Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps)

Excerpt:

> Note: For String parameter type, PowerShell will cast the filter query to a string while processing the command. When using a string variable as a value in the filter component, make sure that it complies with the PowerShell Quoting Rules. For example, if the filter expression is double-quoted, the variable should be enclosed using single quotation marks: Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$UserName'". On the contrary, if curly braces are used to enclose the filter, the variable should not be quoted at all: Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$UserName'".

Comment: Hey, Jawed. Thanks for your reply. I tried the above, but the result was the same. Nothing is returned when run inside the For loop. The issue only happens when run inside the For loop. Very strange!

Comment: @Kenny right, just realized Kyle mistake as well... you need to put a break statement when the user is found otherwise It will always return the user info from the last domain

Comment: Ok! I can try that, but why that only be required when using get-aduser with -filter? The same code works fine in a for loop with get-aduser -identity

Comment: You are searching for a user in all domains and suppose that user is in 1st domain, not any other. After it finds the user in the first loop, the user will not be found in other domains and last iteration in the loop will return a blank user. You need to find the user when returned instead of continuing to search other domains

Comment: The `break` tip in the comment is helpful, but the answer is mostly a distraction: while it is advisable to avoid passing script blocks to the `-Filter` parameter, it does work with simple variable references as in the question (unless implicit remoting is involved) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375). It is unfortunate that the official documentation does such a poor job of explaining the issue, as evidenced by the excerpt in your answer. Also, using embedded `'...'` quoting is problematic with full names, as it would break with last names such as `O'Neill`.

Comment: Thank you, Mklement. I've tried out the various suggestions from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075502/get-aduser-filter-will-not-accept-a-variable/44184818#44184818

...but the result is the same