# Change Active Directory titles for all csv users

Tags: powershell, system

I would like to change 150 employees their job title.

I have a csvfile called `Titletest.csv` with columns `UserPrincipalName` [the user.name under it] and `Title` [job title under it]

The PowerShell script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

$users = Import-Csv -Path c:\scripts\Titlestest.csv | Foreach-Object {

$user = $_.user

$title = $_.title

#Selects the specified user and sets Job Title

Get-ADUser -Filter {(UserPrincipalName -eq $user)} | Set-ADUser -Title $title

}
```

I get errors saying:

> Get-ADUser : Variable: 'user' found in expression: $user is not defined.
>   At line:14 char:1
>   + Get-ADUser -Filter {(UserPrincipalName -eq $user)} | Set-ADUser -Titl ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Can someone please advise?

Thank you.

Comment: For this to work properly, your CSV file will need to contain header columns, `user` and `title`, with the appropriate data in them. If your column header is `UserPrincipalName`, then you will need to change to `$user = $_.UserPrincipalName`.

Comment: As an aside: While seductively convenient, it's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is because `$user` has no assignment. You are attempting to assign `$user` the value of a property that does not exist. The header `user` apparently does not exist in your CSV file. See below for how to convert a csv into PowerShell objects and access their properties.

```
# Sample CSV TitleTest.csv
UserPrincipalName,Title
covid19@domain.com,Usurper
jsmith@domain.com,CEO
bossman@domain.com,CFO

Import-Csv -Path c:\scripts\TitleTest.csv | Foreach-Object {
    $user = $_.UserPrincipalName
    $title = $_.Title
    Get-ADUser -Filter 'UserPrincipalName -eq $user' | Set-ADUser -Title $title
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

When using [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) on a proper CSV file, the first row of delimited data will be converted to the properties of all input objects. All succeeding rows will be converted to individual objects with the header properties and output as a collection (array) of those objects. If the `-Header` parameter is used, then values passed into the parameter will become the properties of the objects. It is important to have the same number of delimited items on each row to ensure proper mapping.

Once you are dealing with objects, you can access their property values using the member access operator `.`. The syntax is `object.property`. So since you have headers `UserPrincipalName` and `Title`, you will need to use `$_.UserPrincipalName` and `$_.Title` to access the associated values.

`$_` is the current pipeline object within your `Foreach-Object {}` script block.

Note that you don't technically need to define `$user` and `$title` here. You can just access the properties directly from the current object:

```
Import-Csv -Path c:\scripts\TitleTest.csv | Foreach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.UserPrincipalName)'" |
        Set-ADUser -Title $_.Title
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback. I just tried that but I still get error: Get-ADUser : the search filter cannot be recognized: At line:10 char:5 Get-ADIser -Filter "UserPricipalName -eq ..."   not sure what am I doing wrong.. my script:  Import-Csv -Path C:\scripts\Titlestest.csv | Foreach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.UserPrincipalName)'" |
        Set-ADUser -Title $_.Title
}

Comment: Does your CSV file have commas separating the fields? Inside of your `foreach-object` you could simply output `$_.UserPrincipalName` and `$_.Title` to see if you are returning any data.