# Paste raw content of variable into filter of another command

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have multiple duplicated lines of code, where only "office" name should be different, but criteria which are in the **$paste** variable should be the same.

```
$paste = "extensionAttribute -eq 123"
$users1 = get-aduser -Properties canonicalName -filter {(office -like "ROFL") -and ( $paste )}
$users2 = get-aduser -Properties canonicalName -filter {(office -like "BOFL") -and ( $paste )}
```

While I'm trying to do so (insert the content of **$paste** variable) I'm receiving this kind of error:

```
get-aduser : Error parsing query: '(office -like "ROFL") -and ( $paste )' Error Message: 'syntax error'
at position: '47'.
At line:1 char:10
+ $users = get-aduser -Properties canonicalName...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

How can I avoid this manual inserting every time when I need to change only part of the criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`), not a script block (`{ ... }`)

```
-Filter "(office -like 'ROFL') -and ( $paste )"
```

<sup>As an aside: since `'ROFL'` is not a wildcard expression, there's no benefit to using `-like` over `-eq`.</sup>

That way, the AD provider ends up seeing the following filter, which should work as expected: `(office -like 'ROFL') -and ( extensionAttribute -eq 123 )`

---

As for **what you tried**:

The use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) with the AD cmdlets' `-Filter` parameter is widespread, but conceptually problematic: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

In short: the `-Filter` parameter is *string*-typed, and when you pass it a *script block*, its *verbatim contents* - excluding `{` an `}` - is passed.

That is, in your attempt the AD provider sees the following string as the `-Filter` argument *verbatim*:  `(office -like "ROFL") -and ( $paste )` - and this string is obviously syntactically incorrect, because the `$paste` variable you wanted to be expanded (interpolated) up front was *not* expanded.

When using `-Filter`, it is important to remember:

- You'll invariably pass a *string* as the argument; if you pass a script block, `.ToString()` is called on it first, yielding its verbatim contents.
- The use of a script block can give the mistaken impression that you can pass arbitrary PowerShell expressions as the filter, which is *not* true:

  - While the expression language supported by the `-Filter` parameter is PowerShell-*like*, it only supports only a limited subset of operators *and* the supported operators in part behave *differently* than their PowerShell counterparts - again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).
  - The most notable limitation is that you can only use *simple variable references* (which you cannot even use when you're using implicit remoting), not variable-based *expressions*, such as *property access*; e.g., you can use `$var` in a filter, but you cannot use `$var.Foo` - use an auxiliary variable in that case.