# Powershell variable acts empty

Tags: powershell

In my script, I'm parsing emails and regex-ing into variables. When i write-host or query the variable it shows, but when I try to run it in the script below it acts lick its empty.

I'm saving the variable as `$Branch` `$Branch = $Matches.BRANCH`

`Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like '$($Branch)'"`

I've tried:(when I run this, it runs with no errors, but also nothing shows.)
`Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like $Branch'`

when I try this I get an error that actually shows the contents of the variable in the error.
`Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like "$Branch""`

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'WA AZ1'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like "$Branch""
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADOrganizationalUnit], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADOrganizationalUnit
```

If I manually create the variable and run it, it works and finds the correct OU.

any help would be great, thanks

Comment: the usual format depends on the type of OUTER quotes. [*grin*] so this ... >>> `-Filter 'Name -like $Branch'` <<< otta be this >>> `-Filter "Name -like $Branch"` <<< ///// also `-like` is a wildcard operator, so if you are not including wildcards in that $Var, it just does `-eq` for an exact match.

Comment: "I'm saving the variable as `$Branch`" - _how_? Please show us the code that assigns/saves the branch name to that variable

Comment: I get a parsing error when running with ""    ```Get-ADOrganizationalUnit : Error parsing query: 'Name -like WA AZ1' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '12'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like $Branch"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADOrganizationalUnit], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADOrganizationalUnit```

Comment: @Hweb Your first attempt (`Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like '$($Branch)'"`) is correct (the `$()` is unnecessary, but the result is the same). If the command silently just doesn't return anything, then that's because no OUs can be found matching the search criteria.

Comment: but when i manually change the `$Branch` to "WA AZ1" -(this is the $VAR) it works and finds the OU

Comment: So that means that the value of `$Branch` _isn't_ the string "WA AZ1" as you expect. Show us your email parsing and regex-ing code if you want qualified help

Comment: ` $Branch = $Matches.BRANCH
    Write-Host "Branch     =" " "$Branch -BackgroundColor DarkGreen`

Comment: `Branch     =   WA AZ1` - this is my write-host response

Comment: Thats _not_ a complete example - what was the input string and pattern used in the previous regex match?

Comment: ```$RE = [RegEx]'(?sm)Name:\s+(?<NAME>.*?)$.*?Goes by:\s+(?<Phone>.*?)$.*?Email:\s+(?<EMAIL>.*?)$.*?Phone:\s+(?<OPHONE>.*?)$.*?Mobile:\s+(?<MOBILE>.*?)$.*?SubBranch:\s+(?<SUBBRANCH>.*?)$.*?Branch:\s+(?<BRANCH>.*?)$.*?Branch Address:\s+(?<ADDRESS>.*?)$.*?Title:\s+(?<TITLE>.*?)$.*?EncompassID:\s+(?<ENCOMPASSID>.*?)$.*?Supervisor Email:\s+(?<SUPERVISOR>.*?)$.*'```

Comment: What type is it? (`$Branch.GetType()`) is it null? (`[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Branch)`). Best to add those two in your code just before the line where it seems empty.

Comment: ```IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     True     String                                   System.Object ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like $Branch'` is the most robust syntax to use - it lets the AD provider interpret the `$Branch` variable, so you need no embedded quoting.

- **Caveat**: This syntax only works with simple variable references, not also with *expressions* (e.g., `$Branch.Name`) and doesn't work with *implicitly remoting* AD modules - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

If this produces no output, the implication is that there are no OUs that match the  wildcard expression contained in `$Branch`. (As Lee Dailey points out, use of `-like` is only needed if your comparison value contains wildcard metacharacter `*`; use `-eq` otherwise).

If printing the value of `$Branch` *looks* like it contains the right value, but the filter doesn't work, there may be *hidden characters*, such as trailing spaces or a trailing CR character, if your input string has Windows-style CRLF newlines<sup>[1]</sup>.
You can eliminate both potential problems with a call to `.Trim()`:

```
$Branch = $Matches.BRANCH.Trim()
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like $Branch'
```

---

<sup>[1] To demonstrate a potential problem:

`` $null = "foo`r`n" -match '(?m)^.+$'; $Matches.0 -match "`r" `` returns `$true`, because the `$` only matches a LF character (`` "`n" ``), not also the CR character before it, so `.+` captures the CR as well.</sup>