# Does changing the order of elements affect -Filter performance?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap-query

Say I am querying Active Directory with `Get-ADUser -Filter "ObjectClass -eq 'user' -and 'Name -like '*foo*'"`.

Does reversing the order of `ObjectClass` and `Name` change the order of the query passed to Active Directory and thus affect performance? According to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65441739/3009519), PowerShell converts the `-Filter` into an LDAP query before being passed to the server.

Assuming it does, in what order is the statement evaluated? Left to right, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Some high-level pointers:

- It's fair to *assume* that evaluation is left to right (I have no source to back that up), but whether the translation of the PowerShell-like `-Filter` expression into an LDAP query behind the scenes even preserves that order is not obvious, judging by the juxtaposition of `-Filter` arguments and corresponding LDAP queries in the `Filter Examples` section of the conceptual [about_Active_Directory_Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) help topic: the subexpression order in the `-Filter` isn't consistently preserved there - though that could just be an inaccuracy in the documentation.
- Generally speaking, given that an `-and` operation is *short-circuiting*, you'll get better performance if you place the test that *executes more quickly* on the LHS:

  - This ensures that the comparatively slower test needn't be executed if the quicker one is negative.
  - At least hypothetically, in the case at hand `ObjectClass -eq 'user'` could be quicker, given that  *wildcard* matching (`-like`) is more complex than equality comparison
    (`-eq`).

    - However, both `-eq` and `-like` translate into the *same* operator on the LDAP side, `=`; see the `Supported Operators` in the linked help topic for details.
    - Either way, it may not make much difference in practice in this case.
- The linked help topic also has an `Optimizing Filters` section, excerpted here:

  > You can enhance the search filter behavior by using these guidelines.

  > - Avoid using the Recursive parameter as it intensifies resource usage of
  >   the search operation.

  > - Avoid using bitwise AND operators and bitwise OR operators. For more
  >   information, see the Supported Operators section of this topic.

  > - Avoid using the logical NOT operator.

  > - Break down your search into multiple queries with narrower conditions.