# How to assign multiple 'where' conditions to variable in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I am working on a Powershell script (with a GUI) to help my colleagues easier find redundant and disabled AD accounts.

Here is a little preview...

`$props = "Name, Enabled, PasswordExpired, Company,passwordNeverExpires, Office"`

`$propsAsArray = $props -split ',\s*'`

`Get-ADUser -filter * -properties $propsAsArray  | where {$_.Enabled -eq $true} | where {$_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false}| where {$_.passwordexpired -eq $false} | Select-Object $propsAsArray | Export-csv -Path "C:\report.csv"`

This all works fine and outputs a CSV report.

The snag though is how to assign all the possible combinations and permutations of AD account status to a variable and later substitute in the variable into the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet (depending on which radio button the user clicks in the GUI).

I've tried all can think of but only ever get back the error `Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline`.

I'm sure that `$accountStatus = "where {$_.Enabled -eq $true} | where {$_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false}"` (or subtle variants) are not how it is done.

I'm relatively new to Powershell and am eager to get experience. Thanks, William.

Comment: It is actually not the best idea to query All users from your AD each time you run such a query and filter them afterwards with several `Where-Object`s. Better would be to create the appropriate filter strings to use with the paramter `-Filter` as this puts less stress to your AD.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for tip. The final version of the script will use the 'SearchBase' parameter to reduce the load on the DC(s). I'd gladly the -Filter parameter to find users whose passwords have expired but it looks like that is not possible. My research suggests that 'PasswordExpired' is a method and not a standard property and thus cannot be filtered. The 'chained' where statements are the only workaround that seems to work.

Comment: My code is based on the final suggested solution over at https://serverfault.com/questions/723217/find-out-if-password-expired-or-when-it-expires-for-user-in-a-specific-ou. My main concern is how to get the chained 'Where-Object" statements into a variable that i can substitute into the "Get-ADUser" cmdlet. Thanks.

Comment: @WilliamLombard - i suspect that i am misunderstanding your Question ... but the `W-O` scriptblock can be just like any other scriptblock. put each test in ONE scriptblock with the appropriate `-and` or `-or` operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can condense your multiple `Where-Object` calls by concatenating each condition with *and*:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $propsAsArray | Where-Object {(($_.Enabled -eq $true) -and ($_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false)) -and ($_.passwordexpired -eq $false)} | Select-Object $propsAsArray | Export-csv -Path "C:\report.csv"
```

But as Olaf already pointed out in the comments, it is even better to already use the `-Filter` parameter of [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser). There, you can use a similar combination of your conditions:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {((Enabled -eq $true) -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $true)) -and (passwordexpired -eq $false)} -Properties $propsAsArray | Select-Object $propsAsArray | Export-csv -Path "C:\report.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I assign the chained "Where-Object" statements to a variable that can then later be substituted back into "Get-ADUser" cmdlet (to then produce a report)?. There are going to many variants depending on whether or not the account is still enabled but the password has expired etc etc.

Comment: Thanks, I've just given that a very quick try and it's not throw back any errors. Legend! :-)

Comment: You can store each radio button setting in a variable and insert them instead of `$true` or `$false`. E. g.: `((Enabled -eq $rbEnabled) -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $rbPasswordNeverExpires)) -and (passwordexpired -eq $rbpasswordexpired)`

Comment: Nice, but as an aside: While seductively convenient, the [use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375) is conceptually problematic and can lead to misconceptions. It would work in this case, however.

Answer (score 4):

Note: This answer addresses the question *as asked*, using **a generalized [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)-based solution based on *script blocks* (`{ ... }`)**, but in the case at hand a *string*-based solution based on `Get-ADUser`'s `-Filter` parameter, which efficiently filters *at the source*, as shown in the second command in [Thomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66627924/45375), is preferable.

---

Store an array of [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) representing the conditionals in a variable, and use an array of indices to select which conditionals to apply situationally, based on the user's GUI selections:

```
# All individual conditions to test, expressed as an array of script blocks.
# Note: No need for `-eq $true` to test Boolean properties, and
#       `-eq $false` is better expressed via the `-not` operator.
$blocks = 
  { $_.Enabled },
  { -not $_.PasswordNeverExpires },
  { $_.PasswordExpired }


# Select the subset of conditions to apply using AND logic, using 
# an array of indices, based on the GUI selections.
$indices = 0..2   # e.g., all 3 conditions (same as: 0, 1, 2)

Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties $propsAsArray | Where-Object { 
  # The following is equivalent to combining the conditionals of interest
  # with -and (AND logic):
  foreach ($block in $blocks[$indices]) { # Loop over selected conditionals
    if (-not (& $block)) { return $false } # Test, and return $false instantly if it fails.
  }
  $true # Getting here means that all conditions were met.
}
```

Note how each block is executed via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).