# Get AD user properties from Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, get-aduser

I am trying to filter the values of a property in Active Directory.

I tried:

```
 Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties physicalDeliveryOfficeName | Where-Object (($_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName -like "NICE")) | Select-Object physicalDeliveryOfficeName, name 

Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties physicalDeliveryOfficeName | Select-Object physicalDeliveryOfficeName, name | Where-Object (($_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName -like "NICE"))
```

I did not get any errors, but no results either.

I searched all users with `physicaldeliverofficename` is (myvalue). I would like to display name and office.

Comment: You probably want `-clike '*NICE*'` instead of `-like 'NICE'`

Comment: `Get-ADuser -LDAPFilter "(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=*NICE*)"` is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **syntax problem**:

The [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)'s (positionally implied) `-FilterScript` parameter expects a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) argument - `{ ... }` - *not* a parenthesized expression (`(...)`).<sup>[1]</sup>

Therefore:

```
# Note the { ... } around the expression passed to Where-Object
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties physicalDeliveryOfficeName | 
  Where-Object { $_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq "NICE" } # | ...
```

<sup>Note: Since `"NICE"` is a *literal* string rather than a *wildcard pattern*, I've used the `-eq` instead of the `-like` operator. If you doe need to find `"NICE"` *as a substring*, use something like `-like "*NICE*"` or, for case-*sensitive* matching, `-clike "*NICE*"`, as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) suggests.</sup>

Note that you may alternatively use [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax), which obviates the need for a script block and allows use of individual parameters (also note the absence of `$_.`, which is implied):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties physicalDeliveryOfficeName | 
  Where-Object physicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq "NICE" # | ...
```

---

**Taking a step back**:

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) suggests performing the **filtering *at the source*, by using [`Get-ADUser`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375)'s `-Filter` or `-LDAPFilter` parameter**, which is **much more efficient**; e.g.:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq "NICE"'
```

As an aside: There are many examples out there that use script-block syntax with `-Filter` (`-Filter { ... }`), but the `-Filter` parameter accepts a *string* and that string, even though it supports PowerShell-*like* syntax, is interpreted *by the AD provider*, so it's better to pass a string to begin with - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] If you use `(...)`, the expression's value gets bound to the `-Property` parameter instead, and is therefore interpreted as a *property name* whose value - assuming such a property even exists - is interpreted as a Boolean that determines whether the input object at hand should be filtered in or not. If the expression doesn't evaluate to the name of a property that exists on an input object, `$false` is implied, and the input object is filtered *out*. In your case, this predictably resulted in *no* objects being filtered in and therefore no output.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The `Select-Object` cmdlet is used to select **only the columns** you want from a larger object or list.

For instance:

```
 C:\git\Core> gsv Spooler | fl

Name                : Spooler
DisplayName         : Print Spooler
Status              : Running
DependentServices   : {Fax}
ServicesDependedOn  : {RPCSS, http}
CanPauseAndContinue : False
CanShutdown         : False
CanStop             : True
ServiceType         : Win32OwnProcess, InteractiveProcess
```

Get-Service returns Service Objects which have a lot of properties.  If I only want certain ones, I'd use it like so:

```
 C:\git\Core> gsv Spooler | Select Name,Status

Name                : Spooler
Status              : Running
```

You're using the cmdlet and probably discarding the columns which have the values you need.  Run your one-liner again and remove the `Select-Object` cmdlet to see all of the columns availble, till you find the one that pertains to the Office.

Comment: `select` is an alias for `select-object` - they _should be_ identical commands.

Comment: They are identical, I'm just saying that the behavior of `Select-Object` is to only select certain properties from an object.