# New-MailboxExportRequest quote issue

Tags: powershell, escaping, exchange-server, pst

I'm trying to get the following command into a program I am developing in PowerShell studio, I'm having some issues figuring out the escaping sequence here, and testing takes forever since I have to import the PST just to view the data :(

Consider the following command which works correctly from the shell...

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox user@domain.com -Name JobName -IncludeFolders "#Inbox#/*","#SentItems#" -ContentFilter {(Received -gt "06/10/2022") -and (Sent -gt "06/10/2022")} -FilePath "\\Server\Folder\MyPST.pst"
```

I am using variables inside program designer, so my actual code looks like this...

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $mailbox -Name $jobname -IncludeFolders $IncludeFolders -ContentFilter {(Received -gt "$RecDate") -and (Sent -gt "$SentDate")} -FilePath "$FilePath"
```

Basically I need to get the first code sample working using variables, however the -IncludeFolders and -ContentFilter parameters require some escaping I can't seem to figure out. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please show us how you instantiate these variables so we can see what they contain

Comment: Sure, and thanks for the reply @theo. The form looks like this, all I do is pass the user input in variables to the command. [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgBAbImA7NSlgZpgzrqkhfzRmzLcfw?e=2RrmV6)

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**:

- You need to enclose your `-ContentFilter` argument in `"..."` overall in order to support embedding variable values, which you can themselves enclose in *embedded* `'...'` quoting:

  ```bash
  -ContentFilter "(Received -gt '$RecDate') -and (Sent -gt '$SentDate')"
  ```
- *No* special syntax considerations apply with respect to using a variable with 
  `-IncludeFolders`: Just make sure that variable `$IncludeFolders` contains an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays) of strings identifying the target folders; applied to your example:

  ```bash
  $IncludeFolders = '#Inbox#/*', '#SentItems#'
  ```

  - If the list of folders must be *parsed from user input* provided  *as a single string* (`$textbox5.text` in this example) do the following to convert this single string to an *array* of names:

    ```bash
     # If $textbox5.text contains string '#Inbox#/*, #SentItems#', 
     # the result is the same as above.
     $IncludeFolders = ($textbox5.text -split ',').Trim()
    ```

Read on for background information and caveats re `-ContentFilter`.

Note:

- The **`-ContentFilter` information below also applies to other Exchange cmdlets that accept filters**, such as [`Get-Recipient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-recipient) with its `-Filter` parameter.
- It also applies analogously to the `-Filter` parameter used with AD (Active Directory) cmdlets such as `Get-ADUser`, although the situation there is complicated by the fact that the AD provider *does* support evaluation of PowerShell variables, but only in *simple* cases - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

---

- [`New-MailboxExportRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-mailboxexportrequest)'s **`-ContentFilter` expects a *string* argument, not a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`)**, which you've used in your question.

  - **While you can *situationally* get away with a script block, it is best avoided** for two reasons:

    - When a script block is used *as a string* (converted to one), string interpolation (embedding the values of variables in the string) is *not* supported - a script block stringifies to its *verbatim content* (sans `{` and `}`).
    - Conceptually, use of a script block can give the mistaken impression that an *arbitrary piece of PowerShell code* may be passed, which is *not* the case: `-ContentFilter` supports a domain-specific syntax only that only *emulates* a limited set of PowerShell features, called  **[OPath filter syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/recipient-filters#additional-opath-syntax-information)**.

      - Notably, evaluation of PowerShell variables is *not* supported - their *values* must be *embedded in the string up front*, by PowerShell, using string interpolation.
- Therefore:

  - **It's best to use a *string* argument with `-ContentFilter` to begin with.**
  - Since you do need **to *embed variable values*, you need *string interpolation*, via an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)**, inside of which you may quote values with `'...'` for syntactical convenience.
  - **In case there is *no* need to embed variable values, use a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)**, inside of which you may quote values with `"..."`, as in your question. (In effect, this is the equivalent of the (ill-advised) use of `{ ... }`).

**Applied to your example**: The following embeds the (stringified) values of variables `$RecDate` and `$SentDate` in your `-ContentFilter` argument:

```bash
# Note the use of "..." for the outer quoting, and 
# '...' for the embedded quoting.
-ContentFilter "(Received -gt '$RecDate') -and (Sent -gt '$SentDate')"
```

**Caveats**:

- If the values of the variables to embed themselves contain `'`, use *escaped* embedded `"..."` quoting instead; e.g., `` `"$var`" ``

  - If a value could contain `'` and/or `"` and you don't know which, you'd have to use an extra layer of up-front string interpolation on the PowerShell side to *escape* one of them, depending on the embedded quoting character chosen, using `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), using a [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation:
  - In this escaping you must technically satisfy the *OPath* filter syntax requirements; the linked help OPath topic suggests that, like in PowerShell, `''` can be used to escape `'` inside a `'...'` string; e.g.: 
    `-ContentFilter "Body -like '$($var -replace "'", "''")*'"`
- While, as stated, OPath filters do *not* support evaluating PowerShell variable references in general, the following [automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) - which are conceptually *constants* - *are* recognized (the linked help topic calls them *system values*):

  - `$true`, `$false`
  - `$null`
  - Therefore, if you use `"..."` for the outer quoting (for string interpolation), the `$` in these variables must be escaped with `` ` `` (the so-called backtick, PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters)), to prevent *PowerShell* from replacing these variable references with their values up front:

    - `` `$true ``, `` `$false ``
    - `` `$null ``

Comment: Thanks for this response @mklement0. I've modified my code to test this example. Question though that is tripping me up, would I have to use the double quotes in the textbox that is accepting the user input? Or would you leave the double quotes out in this part?  [Link to screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgBAbImA7NSlgZpgzrqkhfzRmzLcfw)

Comment: @SeeShellRun, no, what the user types should _not_ include double quotes, and neither should you add them programmatically. However, I suggest trimming leading and trailing whitespace first, and checking if the input is recognized as a date (e.g., `[datetime] '06/10/2022'`); PowerShell assumes that `06` is the _month_ in this example, irrespective of what culture is in effect. Not sure what OPath expects.

Comment: Thanks, I have been testing the code, seems like the Export job runs, but it never exports the folders I specify. Text fields looks like this [ScreenShot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgBAbImA7NSlgZphMlc3GoUaPu3HZw)

Once I import the PST and expand it, the folders I specify in the text field are not there. Seems like its not taking my -ContentFilter switch.

Comment: Here is the most recent code I am using based on your last helpful recommendation.

`New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $ExportMailbox -Name "$JobName" -IncludeFolders "'$SourceRootFolder'" -ContentFilter "(Received -gt '$ReceivedDate') -and (Sent -gt '$SentDate')"  -FilePath $FilePath`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "Seems like its not taking my -IncludeFolders switch".. Not -ContentFilter

Comment: This is what it looks like when I debug... [Debug Screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgBAbImA7NSlgZpiqHRNaeaVaJ5N6g)

Comment: @SeeShellRun, please see my update (top section) re `-IncludeFolders`

Comment: Ah, ok missed that, thanks. Here is the code I have below, this doesn't appear to be working, think it is expecting the commas. User input could either but with the comma or without the comma, so I cant just use `$IncludeFolders = '#Inbox#/*', '#SentItems#'`

Here is my code

`$Folders = $textbox5.text
$Folders2 = $Folders.split(",")
$IncludeFoldersArray = @()
foreach ($item in $Folders2)
{
$IncludeFoldersArray += $item
}`

Then I use $IncludeFoldersArray for the -IncludeFolders switch in my code.

Comment: @SeeShellRun, see my update about how to efficiently parse a _single string_ such as `'#Inbox#/*, #SentItems#'` into an array of tokens. Generally, please note that we're getting pretty far away from the original question, and that you should generally either (a) state all requirements _up front_, as much as possible or (b) create _new_ question posts for _follow-up_ questions.