# Trying to use Powershell to filter Active Directory. Having issues combining two filters

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Still new to powershell, so basic things can trip me up sometimes. I've been using a couple of filters against our Active Directory Tenant. Both run fine individually, but when combining the two, the command runs but fails to return any results. I know there are absolutely users in our tenant which match the filters, so I'm wondering where I've gone wrong. Hence me reaching out here for help!

```
$daysInactive =  [DateTime]::Today.Adddays(-30)
Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True' -and passwordlastset -le '$daysInactive'"
```

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong with the above would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting any errors? This seems to work fine as is in my environment.

Comment: Also, you indicate that you are looking for users that match the filter but you are using Get-ADComputer not Get-ADUser.

Comment: Ah, good catch- I'd tested against both Users and computer, I'll change the code sample back to Get-AdUser

Comment: The command is running, but returning no results, when there are absolutely users in the environment which meet both filter requirements. Hence, my confusion... :-(

Comment: you should really be comparing it to `$true`. Perhaps you're confusing `-le` with `-ge`? There seems to be nothing wrong with your code and if you are certain their is a user that matches that criteria, can you post their returned properties from a `Get-ADUser` query with the *passwordlastset* property as well?

Comment: I did exactly that, using ```Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -properties PasswordLastSet ``` to confirm that my above command should be returning results.

Comment: This does not work as written for me; try `Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True' -and passwordlastset -le $($daysInactive.ToFileTimeUTC())"` ?  PasswordLastSet is [stored](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-pwdlastset) as "number of 100 nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC)", so I imagine the PowerShell wrapper turning it to-from `[DateTime]` has some date formats it can and can't read, maybe the format varies with locale and country?

Comment: Ahh. that works! Thank you so much. I suspected the date format may be the cause, but hadn't yet found the way to fix it.