# How to find UPN that contains digit?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

i would like to know how to find UPN that constain digit with -filter?

```
Get-ADUser -filter {(UserPrincipalName -contains "I dont know what i should add here @contoso.com")} -properties userprincipalname | select userprincipalname
```

Comment: `Get-ADUser` uses Powershell expressions for filters (as contrasted with WQL, a SQL subset). If you had a random string - not necessarily a `UserPrincipalName` from an `ADUser` object - that looked like "Smith123@contoso.com", how would you do it?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, they're _similar_ to PowerShell expressions, but much more limited, with subtle differences in behavior - they're not sophisticated enough to do what is required here.

Comment: As an aside: the `-Filter` language doesn't support the `-contains` operator, only PowerShell does. However, there it does _not_ look for substrings, it tests if an _array_ contains a given element _as a whole_ - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains).

Comment: @mklement0 - point taken - although that implies that he _can't_ use `-match`, which was what I was thinking of, more-or-less combining your `Get-ADUser` and `Where-Object` into the filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-Filter` argument of AD cmdlets, which accepts a *string*, [uses PowerShell-*like* syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), but with only a *limited subset of supported operators*, some of which work in subtly different ways than in PowerShell.

The filter language is *not* sophisticated enough to do the matching you want: the only pattern matching supported is via *wildcards*, which are limited to use of `*`, using the `-like` operator.<sup>[1]</sup>

Therefore, use `-Filter` for *pre*-filtering with `-like`, then use a [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call to let *PowerShell* filter the results down, using its [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) capabilities:

```bash
Get-ADUser -Filter 'UserPrincipalName -like "*@contoso.com"' -Properties UserPrincipalName | 
  Where-Object UserPrincipalName -match '\d'
  Select-Object UserPrincipalName
```

Note:

- `-match '\d'` matches if at least one digit (`\d`) is present in the input.
- I've used a *string* rather than a script block (`{ ... }`) to specify the `-Filter` argument, because that's what `-Filter` expects. While seductively convenient, the use of script blocks is conceptually problematic and can lead to misconceptions - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

---

<sup>[1] By contrast, *PowerShell's* [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like) operator supports PowerShell's more fully-featured [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards). Also, the AD `-Filter`'s language at least situationally interprets `*` to mean: *at least one* character, whereas PowerShell's wildcard expression interpret it as *zero* or more.</sup>