# Struggling with PSCustomObject in Compare-Object

Tags: powershell, active-directory, filtering, get-aduser

**Question:**

Anyone understand why I'm receiving the following error for my `title` property in my PSCustomObject inside a `foreach`?  I understand what the error is stating, just confused on the 'why' of it.
Everything else works, I'm confused why `$_.inputobject` returns "Firstname Lastname" just fine in the `user` property, but can't be used in `-filter` scriptblock and is unrecognized as an object type in PSCustomObject even though it returns the expected value in the `user` column.

**Error:**

```
Get-ADUser : Property: 'inputobject' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.
```

**Code:**

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $users.name -DifferenceObject $results.user | foreach {
    $_.sideindicator = $_.sideindicator -replace "<=","No assigned device"
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        user = $_.inputobject
        title = Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $_.inputobject} -Properties * | % title
        device_status = $_.sideindicator
    }
}
```

Comment: try with `-Filter "name -eq '$($_.inputobject)'" -Properties title` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the standard advice applies:

- While seductively convenient, **avoid the [use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375)** with AD (Active Directory) cmdlets, because it is conceptually problematic and can lead to misconceptions.

Second, the solution is to use an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) instead:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "name -eq `"$($_.inputobject)`"" -Properties title
```

<sup>Note: Given that your operand contains no *wildcard metacharacters*, there's no reason to use `-like`.</sup>

As for the error message:

- At least historically, only *simple, stand-alone* variable references - e.g., `$_` - were supported in the *string* that is (ultimately) passed to the `[string]`-typed `-Filter` argument, not also *expressions*, which inlcudes attempts to access a *property*, e.g. `$_.InputObject`
- The error message suggests that the AD provider - now? - *does* try to evaluate an expression such as `$_.InputObject`, but - seemingly - only looks for *type-native* properties, whereas a [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject) instance's properties are *dynamic* properties.
- Perhaps someone can shed more light on this (I don't have access to AD).

Comment: Thanks, adding to quote block did the trick.  I've had major issues in the past with quote blocks for some more complex filtering, and that error almost made it seem like PS wouldn't have recognized InputObject regardless, so I didn't bother trying xD.  Funny enough, I did previously try "$($_.inputobject)" inside the scriptblock and it returned empty, so I figured it wouldn't work in a filter quote block, PS makes my head hurt :). Also I do switch to -eq after I get -like working, I just like to use -like to troubleshoot with * if need be.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Eric. The problem with using a _script block_ `{ ... }` with `-Filter` is that it is _not_ evaluated like a regular PowerShell script block, because it is (a) converted to a _string_ first and (b)  interpreted by the _AD provider_, not PowerShell. And while the syntax supported in such strings is _similar_ to that in PowerShell script blocks, it is both much more limited and exhibits subtle differences in behavior. That is why it is generally preferable to construct the `-Filter` argument _as a(n expandable) string_ to begin with. The linked answer has more information.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link @mklement0.  Do you know of any good resources for some of these more nuanced best practices?  Some of the intricacies with PS or certain modules isn't very intuitive or standard, and I struggle with finding good articles or lectures on best practice outside of beginner level.  I suppose checking MS KBs for specific cmdlet options or arguments is a good start.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any recommendations, @Eric, except to say that sites like this one are often a good source of information of what the official docs don't cover.