# Powershell Forms Textbox value invalid?

Tags: powershell, winforms, filter, active-directory

Can you please let me know what is wrong with this code?

```
$SearchUser.Add_Click(
{
  $Output.text = 
   Get-AdUser -Filter "Surname -like $entry" |
   select name, samaccountname
}
)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Get-aduser : Error parsing query: 'Surname -like rondon' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '15'.
At line:50 char:11
+ $search = Get-aduser -Filter "Surname -like $entry" | select name, sa ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingExcepti
   on,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Filter works standalone in powershell but not via the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Your [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser) `-Filter` argument isn't well-formed; use:

- *Either*: `` "Surname -like `"$entry`"" `` (up-front string interpolation, requires *embedded quoting*)

  - Note: Only *stand-alone* variable references can be embedded as-is inside [expandable `"..."` literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings); embedding *expressions* or *commands* requires enclosure in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), e.g.  `` "Surname -like `"$($entry.Text)`"" `` or
    `` "Surname -like `"$(Get-Entry)`"" ``
- *Or*: `'Surname -like $entry'` (let the AD provider evaluate the variable, do *not* use embedded quoting)

  - Note: This approach fundamentally *only* works with *stand-alone* variable references, not with attempts to access *properties* (e.g <del>`'Surname -like $entry.Text'`</del> or subexpressions (e.g. <del>`'Surname -like $(Get-EntryName)'`</del>)
  - While the form `{ Surname -like $entry }` is often seen in practice, it is *best avoided* so as to prevent conceptual confusion - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `-Filter "Surname -like $entry"`

- Since you're using an [*expandable* (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), i.e. up-front *string interpolation*, the value of `$entry` is placed as-is inside the resulting string value.
- Thus, with `$entry` containing verbatim `rondon`, what the `-Filter` argument receives is verbatim `Surname -like rondon`, which causes a *syntax* error, because the RHS of the `-like` operator must either be a *quoted string* or a *reference to a PowerShell variable*.

  - It is important to note that while the `-Filter` parameter expects expression that are PowerShell-*like*, they are *not* PowerShell expressions, and instead interpreted by the Active Directory provider. The expression language supported in a `-Filter` argument is both much more limited than what PowerShell supports and exhibits subtle yet important differences in behavior. Again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375) for background information.