# Variable not defined when trying to list a group of AD user from a CSV using Get-ADUser -Filter {displayName

Tags: powershell, foreach, powershell-remoting, get-aduser

I am using the below code to try and pull out a list of last logon times for a group of users contained in a CSV file.  I have a test domain at home and the script below works fine.  However, when I try it on my work prod AD I get the following error.

```
Get-ADUser: Variable: 'dname' found in expression: $dname is not defined.
```

This is the script I have put together.

```
$list = Import-Csv -Path "C:\data\PowerShell\UserInfo.csv"

ForEach ($user in $list) {
    $dname = $user.Displayname
    Get-ADUser -Filter {displayName -eq $dname} -Properties lastLogon | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, @{Name="LastLogon"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogon)}} | Export-CSV -Path "C:\data\PowerShell\user_last_login.csv" -append -NoTypeInformation
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

For the reasons explained in the next section, **your `Get-ADUser` *proxy command*<sup>[1]</sup> doesn't see your local variables inside a `-Filter` argument**. Therefore, **use [*string interpolation*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) instead**, so as to directly incorporate the variable *value* into the `-Filter` argument (note the need to use embedded double-quoting (`` `" ``)around the expanded value):

```bash
Get-ADUser -Filter "displayName -eq `"$dname`"" -Properties lastLogon
```

As an aside:

- While `-Filter {displayName -eq $dname}` does work if `Get-ADUser` is the regular (non-proxy) cmdlet from the [`ActiveDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory) module that directly talks to an AD server, the [script-block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) syntax (`{ ... }`) - while convenient - is conceptually problematic and can lead to misconceptions, so `-Filter 'displayName -eq $name'` may be preferable - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375) for background information.
  However, in the case at hand (implicit remoting, see below) using string interpolation is the only solution.

---

##### Background information: The limitations of *implicit remoting*:

Your symptom implies that **your Active Directory commands are provided via *implicit remoting***, where a local proxy module is used to relay calls to a remote machine behind the scenes using PowerShell's [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) feature (the proxy modules are typically created with the [`Export-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-pssession) cmdlet; [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/ff720181(v=msdn.10)) provides an introduction to implicit remoting).

In a nutshell, the proxy module contains proxy commands of the same name as their remote counterparts, implemented as PowerShell *functions* that relay the calls to their remote counterparts.<sup>[1]</sup>

While this proxying mostly works as intended, it has **side effects**:

- **References to *local* variables, such as in your `-Filter` argument cannot work**, because the remote command that ultimately executes the operation knows nothing about the local caller's variables.

  - Note that AD module's `-Filter` parameter is unusual in that it expects a *string*, inside of which (stand-alone only) references to PowerShell variables are recognized; while it is common to see [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments, they are actually *converted to strings* during parameter binding; while using script blocks is syntactically *convenient*, it obscures the real behavior (it can falsely suggest that the argument is a *piece of PowerShell code*, which it isn't) and can lead to conceptual confusion - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375) for background information.
  - In cases where *actual* script blocks are passed to remoting commands, notably in the context of [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command), the values of local variables can be embedded in them via the [`$using:`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier) scope.
- The following side effect applies to script modules in general (*script modules* are those whose exported commands are implemented as PowerShell functions rather than as binary cmdlets, as is the case in implicit remoting):

  - **Script modules do *not* see a caller's [preference variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables)** (except if the call happens to be made from the *global* scope, which in scripting is typically *not* the case), such as `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`.
  - For a detailed discussion, see [GitHub issue #4568](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568)
- The following side effect applies not only to PowerShell's [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) in general, but also to background [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs) and "mini shells" (in-session PowerShell CLI calls with script blocks):

  - **Redirecting, capturing, or suppressing [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams)** other than the success (`1`) and error output stream (`2`) is **inconsistently supported** with **partial inability to redirect and/or capture streams**, and partial inability to effectively **suppress output streams**.
  - For details, see [GitHub issue #9585](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9585).

---

<sup>[1] Given that [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser) is normally a *binary cmdlet*, an easy way to test if a given `Get-ADUser` command is a proxy command is to use `(Get-Command Get-ADUser).CommandType -eq 'Function'`.</sup>